# Iterate over Async Function with For Loop (db query, Node.js)

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise

Im in the last part of my project and I'm trying to insert data from json in my MySQL db here are my sample data

```
{"data": 
[{"cpos": "g", "cfname": "e", "clname": "ejercito", "cvcount": "4"}, 
{"cpos": "g", "cfname": "j", "clname": "ejercito", "cvcount": "5"}]}
```

and that sample data is being parsed by my function (sorry for long function)

```
checkPositionCandidateInsertVote: function(ref, prid, json, callback){
    var len = json.data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var fn = (json.data[i].cfname).toLowerCase();
        var ln = (json.data[i].clname).toLowerCase();
        var c = json.data[i].cvcount;
        console.log(fn, ' ', c);
        switch((json.data[i].cpos).toLowerCase()){
            case "g":
                module.exports.getCandiName(fn, ln, "Governor", function(dataa){
                    //dataa.id
                    module.exports.insertVotes(prid, ref, c, dataa.id, function(res){
                    });
                });
                break;
            case "vg":
                module.exports.getCandiName(fn, ln, "Vice Governor", function(dataa){
                    //dataa.id
                    module.exports.insertVotes(prid, ref, c, dataa.id, function(res){
                    });
                });
                break;
            case "m":
                module.exports.getCandiName(fn, ln, "Mayor", function(dataa){
                    //dataa.id
                    module.exports.insertVotes(prid, ref, c, dataa.id, function(res){
                    });
                });
                break;
            case "vm":
                module.exports.getCandiName(fn, ln,  "Vice Mayor", function(dataa){
                    //dataa.id
                    module.exports.insertVotes(prid, ref, c, dataa.id, function(res){
                    });
                });
                break;
            case "bm":
                module.exports.getCandiName(fn, ln, "Board Member", function(dataa){
                    //dataa.id
                    module.exports.insertVotes(prid, ref, c, dataa.id, function(res){
                    });
                });
                break;
            case "cg":
            case "cm":
            case "cw":
                module.exports.getCandiName(fn, ln, "Congressman", function(dataa){
                    //dataa.id
                    module.exports.insertVotes(prid, ref, c, dataa.id, function(res){
                    });
                });
                break;
            case "c":
                module.exports.getCandiName(fn, ln, "Councilor", function(dataa){
                    //dataa.id
                    module.exports.insertVotes(prid, ref, c, dataa.id, function(res){
                    });
                });
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

My function/s are working fine but when I check my db the data are wrong in VoteCount part.

**Expected**

```
e ejercito 4
j ejercito 5
```

but in the db is

**Result**

```
e ejercito 5
j ejercito 5
```

How to stop my for loop if my query is not yet finished?

Comment: You can't "pause" a `for` loop to wait for an async operation.  A `for` loop is synchronous.  Instead, you will have to iterate manually, putting an iteration into a function and starting the next iteration manually only when your async operation completes.

Comment: @jfriend00 can you give me some example? this is my first month in nodejs (javascript)

Comment: Here's are some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880715/how-to-synchronize-a-sequence-of-promises/29906506#29906506 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191788/how-to-process-a-big-array-applying-a-async-function-for-each-element-in-nodejs/34191957#34191957

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to stop for loop, there is a beauty of asynchronous nature of JS.

Thing is that by the time `module.exports.insertVotes(prid, ref, c, dataa.id, function(res){});` is executed, for loop already went through, so you end up with las index for all cases.

To fix that you can use `forEach` [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) . Each iteration will have its own scope.

```
    checkPositionCandidateInsertVote: function(ref, prid, json, callback){

    json.data.forEach(function(listItem, i){

        var fn = (json.data[i].cfname).toLowerCase();
        var ln = (json.data[i].clname).toLowerCase();
        var c = json.data[i].cvcount;
        console.log(fn, ' ', c);
        switch((json.data[i].cpos).toLowerCase()){
            case "g":
                module.exports.getCandiName(fn, ln, "Governor", function(dataa){
                    //dataa.id
                    module.exports.insertVotes(prid, ref, c, dataa.id, function(res){
                    });
                });
                break;
            ...
            ...
            ...

            case "c":
                module.exports.getCandiName(fn, ln, "Councilor", function(dataa){
                    //dataa.id
                    module.exports.insertVotes(prid, ref, c, dataa.id, function(res){
                    });
                });
                break;
        }

    });


}
```

Comment: thankyouu! can you explain the difference of foreach and for-loop?
so that I can apply it of the same occur again

Comment: Happy to help! To understand what going on here, you need to understand few basic JS concepts. I would start with JS scoping https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/  >> callbacks