# Execute promise one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a test_func that needs to be executed sequentially, ie; first_call, second_call, third_call.

Current output:-

```
started == first_call
VM81:49 status in : first_call  pending
VM81:47 started == second_Call
VM81:47 started == third_Call
VM81:49 status in : second_Call  pending
VM81:49 status in : third_Call  pending


function test_func(call_from){
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
    console.log('started ==',call_from)
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("status in :",call_from + '  ' +  deferred.state());
    deferred.resolve();
  },5000);

  return deferred.promise();
};
test_func('first_call').then(function(){
    test_func('second_Call')
  }).then(function(){
    test_func('third_Call')
  })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/44Lm3at0/

Comment: possibly here can be your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880715/how-to-synchronize-a-sequence-of-promises

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve promises one after another (i.e. in sequence)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence)

Comment: The first `.then` callback needs to be `return test_func('second_Call')`

Comment: May I also suggest async? It's a library that offers a lot of functions helping you with control flow and other challenges that come with async programming.

Comment: Convert Promises to callbacks @newBee ?

Comment: Async works with callbacks, true. This was just a general hint however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you send each `Promise` downstream in the `Promise` chain with  `return`, like:

```
test_func('first_call')
  .then(function(){
    return test_func('second_Call');
  })
  .then(function(){
    return test_func('third_Call');
  })
  .then(function() {
     console.log('done');
   });
```

And see updated js fiddle to prove it:
https://jsfiddle.net/44Lm3at0/1/

To add on, if you don't `return` the `Promise`, each item in the chain will run in parallel (offset by a little bit of time) instead of sequentially. By returning them, you inform JavaScript that you want to "wait" for the `Promise` to complete, allowing the chain of the `then` to work properly.