# Wait On For Loop In Node Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm trying to run a sequence of promises using the Q library.

The merge notes function creates a new note in the database and I have to run the functions in order due to some unique constraints.

The promises are running in sequence no problem, but I need to push all of the newNotes into an array in workNotes and then resolve that array.

Everything I have tried resolves the promise before the chain is over.

*To clarify the problem, I need to resolve notesList after the chain has completed and every resulting newNote has been pushed to notesList.*

```
workNotes(notes){
    var _this = this;
    var notesList = [];
    return new Promise(
        function(resolve,reject){
            var chain = Q.when();
            notes.forEach(function(note){
                chain = chain.then(function(newNote){
                   _this.notesList.push(newNote);
                   return _this.mergeNotes(note);
                 });
             });
            resolve(notesList)
        }          
    );
}


mergeNotes(notes){
    return new Promise(
        function(resolve,reject){
            doSomething(note)
            .then(function(newNote){
             resolve(newNote);
            })   
         }       
    );
}
```

Comment: If your `doSomething()` is asynchronous, then you need to pass it a callback and use the completion callback to call `resolve()`.  Otherwise, you're resolving the promise BEFORE the asynchronous operation is done.  If this is not your problem, then please describe in more detail exactly what you want help with.

Comment: FYI, a typical design pattern for processing an array in sequence uses `.reduce()`.  You can see that in the 3rd and 4th code examples here: [How to synchronize a sequence of promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880715/how-to-synchronize-a-sequence-of-promises/29906506#29906506).

Comment: Also, not sure why you're using `Q.when()`  when `Promise.resolve()` is apparently available (since you're using `new Promise()`).

Comment: Your `workNotes` never calls `resolve` or `reject`? And it looks very much like the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Where's that array that you want to push to? What did you try?

Comment: @jfriend00 - thanks for that link. Looking at it now

Comment: @Bergi I added the resolve and the array.

Comment: @jfriend00 doSomething actually returns a promise also. It's working fine. To clarify the problem, I need to resolve notesList after the chain has completed and every resulting newNote has been pushed to notesList.

Comment: `resolve(chain.then(() => notesList))`? You might want to put this on [CodeReview.SE] afterwards, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the useless `_this.` (notice that `this` is not about scope!), avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it), swap the order of calls to `push` and 
`mergeNotes`, and use `reduce` instead of `forEach` to fold an array to a single value:

```
function workNotes(notes) {
    var notesList = [];
    return notes.reduce(function(chain, note) {
        return chain.then(function() {
            return mergeNotes(note);
        }).then(function(newNote){
            notesList.push(newNote);
        });
    }, Q.when()).then(function() {
        return notesList;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi. This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Change `mergeNotes()` to return the new promise:

```
mergeNotes(notes){
    return doSomething(note);
}
```

You were returning a promise, but it was not connected in any way to the `doSomething()` promise and thus it didn't wait for that.

Avoid the [promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) of wrapping an existing promise in a newly created promise.  Instead, just return the promise you already have.

I'd change the rest of your code to this:

```
workNotes(notes) {
    let allNotes = [];
    return notes.reduce(function(p, note) {
        return p.then(function() {
            return mergeNotes(note);
        }).then(function(newNote) {
            allNotes.push(newNote);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve()).then(function() {
        return allNotes;
    });
}
```

---

With the Bluebird promise library, you could take advantage of `Promise.mapSeries()` which processes an array in sequence and returns a resolved array which is exactly what you need:

```
workNotes(notes) {
    return Promise.mapSeries(notes, function(note) {
        return mergeNotes(note);
    });
}
```

The resolved value of the promise returned by `workNotes()` will be an array of notes.

Comment: Or even simpler, `var mergeNotes = doSomething;` :-)

Comment: @Bergi - I assume the real code does something more than that in there.  But, yes if that's all there is, then there's no need for a wrapping function.  `doSomething()` can just be called directly.