# Running promise in sequence with the result of the previous

Tags: bluebird

With the following example using async/await, I would to convert it in explicit Promise:

```
conts promises = [promise1, promise2, promise3, promise4]

async function (message) 
{
  let transformedMessage = message
  for(let p of promises) 
  {
      transformedMessage = await p(transformedMessage)
  }
  return transformedMessage
}
```

I didn't find any collection which permits to reuse the resolve value as argument of the following iteration.

Comment: What exactly is your question?   If `p` is actually a promise, then `await p(transformedMessage)` does not make any sense because you don't execute promises (they are objects, not functions).  If `p` is a function that returns a promise, then that could work, but your code nomenclature is really messed up.

Comment: Also, `for (let p in promises)` should be `for (let p of promises)` to iterate the array.  Still not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Your are right, a typing error occured, it should be a for...of
The goal is to play a sequence of promises and reuse the result in the call of the next promise

Comment: Maybe this is related: [How to synchronize a sequence of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880715/how-to-synchronize-a-sequence-of-promises/29906506#29906506)

Comment: Great, I didn't really understood how to use Promise.reduce, but now it is more clear and it does what I need. Thanks!