# How can asynchronous method in loop executed in sequence?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get data from db for several times. How to set a loop to execute getData() function in interval like 200ms. And if one of them success, rest of them won't be triggered. It's asynchronous method, and different from question here: [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop)

```java
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
setTimeout(getData,200);}
```

This will end up with the output time interval is very close instead of 200ms, since they are asynchronous. Three "setTimeout" are triggered in a short time. like 0.001s 0.002s 0.003s, the output time is 0.201, 0.202, 2.203.

getData() returns a promise. But it can be normal function as long as it works.

Comment: I would suggest moving away from callbacks and towards the new promise paradigm

Comment: It would be helpful to know what flavor of async `getDB` is. Does it return a promise? Take a callback?

Comment: @MarkMeyer  It can be a normal function. I pack it here to return promise, since I need some method after this.

Comment: Lots of options covered here: [How to sequence asynchronous operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880715/how-to-synchronize-a-sequence-of-promises/29906506#29906506).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a loop. Have the function call `setTimeout()` to run itself again if it fails.

```js
var i = 0;

function callGetDB() {
  getDB().then(db => {
    // use DB
  }).catch(() => {
    if (i++ < 3) {
      setTimeout(callGetDB, 200);
    }
  });
}
```

I'm assuming the asynchronous function `getDB()` returns a promise.

Comment: What if they can all get the data successfully. Can I get the thing like "as soon as one of them receive the data, rest of them stop". Your code will execute for three times if first one already got the answer, right?

Comment: The `.catch()` is only executed when the promise fails. So it stops when one of them succeeds.

Comment: I am using your solution. But I just find that if I successfully get the data in second try and resolve() it, it can't be passed to the next funciton in code like . callGetDb().then(data)=>{}.   'data' will be null

Comment: I post specific code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066813/how-can-asynchronous-method-in-recursion-return-result-correctly .   Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by waiting for the `setTimeout` to finish before executing the next `setTimeout`

I don't believe this is possible with callbacks, as is the case with `setTimeout`, so you should transform it into a promise-based call

```js
const promiseSetTimeout = timeout => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, timeout));

const waitManyTimes = async () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        await promiseSetTimeout(200);
        // do something here, like getDB 
        console.log(i);
    }
}

waitManyTimes();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `async/await`:

```
let sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

let main = async() => {
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let db = getDB();
    if (db)
      return db;
    await sleep(200);
  }
};
```

Comment: `getDB` is async right? What are you testing with `if (db)`? If `getDB()` returns a promise, which isn't clear in the question, you'll need to `await` it. If it takes a callback...