# How can asynchronous method in recursion return result correctly?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I asked question about how to run asynchronous method in loop. And I am now doing it in something like recursion.

[How can asynchronous method in loop executed in sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56978584/how-can-asynchronous-method-in-loop-executed-in-sequence)

But now I can't get data pass to final callback(last line of my code), if db data is fetched successfully at second time.

1. I notice the problem may be: second CallGetDB resolve() the data I want but first CallGetDB doesn't get that. Then first CallGetDB finished wihtout resolve anything. But I don't know how to solve it.

```
function CallGetDB(UID) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        GetDynamodb(UID)
        .then((data)=> {
                  console.log("check before if"+JSON.stringify(data));
                  dbResponse = data;
                  resolve(dbResponse);
                }
            )
        .catch((data)=> {
                if(index++ < 2)
                {
                  console.log("This is "+(index+1)+" try to get data from db with UID.");
                  setTimeout(function(){CallGetDB(UID);},100);
                }
                else
                {
                  console.log("Database multi fetch failed");
                  resolve("Database multi fetch failed");
                }
        });
  });
```

```
SendSQS(UID,event).then((data)=>{
    return CallGetDB(data);
 }).then((data)=>{
   console.log("I am at most out:" +JSON.stringify(data));
   response.body=JSON.stringify(data);
   callback(null,response);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping `GetDynamodb(UID)` in a `new Promise` is an anti-pattern since it returns a promise.

Following adds a `retries` parameter with a default to `CallGetDB()` and either returns a new promise in the `catch()`  when retries are within limits.... or throws a new error to get caught in following `catch()`

```
let sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

function CallGetDB(UID, retries = 0) {

  return GetDynamodb(UID)
    .catch((data) => {
      if (retries++ < 2) {
        console.log("This is " + (retries + 1) + " try to get data from db with UID.");
        // return another promise
        return sleep(100).then(() => CallGetDB(UID, retries));

      } else {
        console.log("Database multi fetch failed");
        // throw error to next catch()
        throw new Error("Database multi fetch failed");
      }
    });
}


SendSQS(UID, event).then((data) => {
  return CallGetDB(data);
}).then((data) => {
  console.log("Data Success:" + JSON.stringify(data));
  response.body = JSON.stringify(data);
  callback(null, data);
}).catch(err => /* do something when it all fails*/ );
```

Comment: Thanks, for this pattern. I wonder how new js writer learn things like that? I even don't know how to search this kind of pattern thing if I don't have these code. Like 'How to do async recursion in JS'?

Answer (score 1):

Your promise isn't resolving in the event of an error and an `index` lower than 2. Here:

```
if(index++ < 2){
  console.log("This is "+(index+1)+" try to get data from db with UID.");
  setTimeout(function(){CallGetDB(UID);},100);
}
```

At that point, your promise will never fulfill or reject as the original promise never gets fulfilled and can't `resolve` the JSON data nor does it hit your `else` branch.It becomes an unresolved promise (a promise stalled indefinitely). It will work in the event that `GetDynamodb` fulfills on the first attempt though.

You can fix this by fulfilling the promise inside the `if` branch:

```
setTimeout(function(){resolve(CallGetDB(UID));},100);
```

That being said, you probably shouldn't be wrapping promises like this. This is a somewhat similar approach to yours:

```
let delay = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

function CallGetDB(UID) {
    return GetDynamodb(UID).then(data => {
        console.log("check before if"+JSON.stringify(data));
        return data;
    }).catch(err => {
        if(index++ < 2){
            console.log("This is "+(index+1)+" try to get data from db with UID.");
            return delay(100).then(() => CallGetDB(UID));
        } else {
            console.log("Database multi fetch failed");
            return "Database multi fetch failed";
        }
    });
});
```

You can also use a closure for scoping retries, so you have a proper scope for your `index` variable:

```
let delay = r => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

function CallGetDB(retries) {
    let index = retries;
    return function inner(UID){
        return getDynamodb(UID).then((data)=> {
            console.log("check before if"+JSON.stringify(data));
            return data;
        }).catch(err => {
            if(index--){
                console.log("This is "+(retries-index)+" try to get data from db with UID.");
                return delay(100).then(() => inner(UID));
            } else {
                console.log("Database multi fetch failed");
                return "Database multi fetch failed";
            }
        });
    };
}
```

Which you can now use like: `CallGetDB(2)(data)`