# Browser equivalent of Node.js's async.forEachSeries()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

As part of bootstraper script i am writing for a html template, i am required to use an API for determining names of various countries corresponding to there alpha-3 codes, like CHN for China and GBR for Greate Britian.

I would like to know if there is some JQuery method that will allow me to "iterate" over an array of these alpha-3 country codes and make a GET request to the remote server for the country name corresponding to each code.

Is there a such a method ? Essentially what i am looking for is the web browser equivalent of Node.js's async.forEachSeries() function.

Comment: Multiple choices here: [How to sequence promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880715/how-to-synchronize-a-sequence-of-promises/29906506#29906506).  The simplest in modern browsers is a `for` loop with `await`.  The `.reduce()` loop and a number of the other solutions there work in any browser.  As best I know, jQuery does not have this feature built-in.

Comment: `async.forEachSeries` is not a nodejs function. Maybe you mean the async.js package? You can use that in a browser as well.