# How to synchronously serialize api calls in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, fetch

I have a task that requires fetching api data, with the constraint of **only one outstanding api request at a time**.  Must receive a response, or time out, before issuing the next one. Since fetch (or axios) returns a promise, I can’t figure out how to wait for each promise to fulfill before issuing the next fetch.

I'm handed a large array of api url's that must all be resolved in this one-at-a-time manner before continuing.

I’m using create-react-app’s bundled dev server, and Chrome browser.

Curiously, accomplishing this via a node script is easy, because ‘await fetch’ actually waits.  Not so in my browser environment, where all the fetch requests blast out at once, returning promises along the way.

Here’s a simple loop that results in the desired behavior as a node script.  **My question is how to achieve this one-outstanding-request-at-a-time synchronous serialization in the browser environment?**

```
const fetchOne = async (fetchUrl) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(fetchUrl, { // Or axios instead    
            "headers": {
                'accept': 'application/json',
                'X-API-Key': 'topSecret'
            },
            'method': 'GET'
        })
        const data = await response.json();
        if (response.status == 200) {
            return (data);
        } else {
            // error handling
        }
    } catch(error) {
        // different error handling
    } 
}

const fetchAllData = async (fetchUrlArray) => {
    let fetchResponseDataArray = new Array();
    let fetchResponseDataObject = new Object(/*object details*/);
    for (var j=0; j<fetchUrlArray.length; j++) { // or forEach or map instead
        // Node actually synchronously waits between fetchOne calls,
        //   but react browser environment doesn't wait, instead blasts them all out at once.
        // Question is how to achieve the one-outstanding-request-at-a-time synchronous
        //   serialization in the browser environment?
        fetchResponseDataObject = await fetchOne(fetchUrlArray[j]);
        fetchResponseDataArray.push(fetchResponseDataObject);
    }
    return(fetchResponseDataArray);
}
```

Comment: How is `fetchAllData` being called?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to synchronize a sequence of promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880715/how-to-synchronize-a-sequence-of-promises)

Comment: @Felix. Thank you. I don't quite think so.  The question there seems to be about ensuring the sequencing of calls, rather than their timing.  Still there might be some clues.

Comment: @Tarun. Thank you. As `await fetchAllData`

Comment: Are you sure what you describe is actually happening? Just from scanning your code I would assume that it should do exactly what you want. Can you provide a runnable example? Maybe with something like https://codesandbox.io/s/  ?

Answer (score 3):

If there's a problem, it's with code you haven't shown (perhaps in one of your components, or maybe in your project configuration).

Here's an runnable example derived from the problem you described, which mocks `fetch` and an API, showing you how to iterate each network request synchronously (and handle potential errors along the way):

> Note, handling potential errors at the boundaries where they might occur is a better practice than *only* having a top level `try/catch`: by doing so, you can make finer-grained decisions about what to do in response to each kind of problem. Here, each failed request is stored as `[url, error]` in a separate array so that you can programmatically make decisions if one or more requests failed. (Maybe you want to retry them in a subsequent step, or maybe you want to show something different in the UI, etc.). Note, there's also [`Promise.allSettled()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled), which might be useful to you now or in the future.

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.16.4/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

const {useEffect, useState} = React;

const successChance = {
  fetch: 0.95,
  server: 0.95,
};

function mockApi (url, chance = successChance.server) {
  // Simulate random internal server issue
  const responseArgs = Math.random() < chance
    ? [JSON.stringify({time: performance.now()}), {status: 200}]
    : ['Oops', {status: 500}];
  return new Response(...responseArgs);
}

function mockFetch (requestInfo, _, chance = successChance.fetch) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Simulate random network issue
    if (Math.random() > chance) {
      reject(new Error('Network error'));
      return;
    }
    const url = typeof requestInfo === 'string' ? requestInfo : requestInfo.url;
    setTimeout(() => resolve(mockApi(url)), 100);
  });
}

// Return an object containing the response if successful (else an Error instance)
async function fetchOne (url) {
  try {
    const response = await mockFetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Response not OK');
    const data = await response.json();
    return {data, error: undefined};
  }
  catch (ex) {
    const error = ex instanceof Error ? ex : new Error(String(ex));
    return {data: undefined, error};
  }
}

async function fetchAll (urls) {
  const data = [];
  const errors = [];

  for (const url of urls) {
    const result = await fetchOne(url);
    if (result.data) data.push([url, result.data]);
    else if (result.error) {
      // Handle this however you want
      errors.push([url, result.error]);
    }
  }

  return {data, errors};
}

function Example () {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);

      try {
        const {data, errors} = await fetchAll([
          'https://my.url/api/0',
          'https://my.url/api/1',
          'https://my.url/api/2',
          'https://my.url/api/3',
          'https://my.url/api/4',
          'https://my.url/api/5',
          'https://my.url/api/6',
          'https://my.url/api/7',
          'https://my.url/api/8',
          'https://my.url/api/9',
        ]);
        setData(data);
      }
      catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex);
      }

      setLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Loading: {loading ? '...' : 'done'}</div>
      <ul>
        {
          data.map(([url, {time}]) => (<li
            key={url}
            style={{fontFamily: 'monospace'}}
          >{url} - {time}</li>))
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I hadn't seen this type of "stand-alone" React before. How does one go about:  
1) Executing it locally?  
2) Converting it to a component for the create-react-app environment? 
I'll go to work substituting my URLs and API into your template. I have a feeling useEffect is a key missing ingredient from my original component.    
Will update with results.

Comment: @thoroughlyConfused (1) It's just HTML, so copy + paste it into a `file.html` and open it in your web browser. (2) It's using the UMD versions of React, ReactDOM, and Babel, so all you need to do is copy + paste the JS in between the last `<script>` tags and replace the `const {useEffect, useState} = React;` with `import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';`.