# Cannot get Q then-chaining to work properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q, async.js

I'm trying to use the `Q` promise library to chain together a couple of `async` methods to change an array of objects I've got. I think I'm close, but I'm making a mistake somewhere and getting the error:

> ```
>        resolve(sizes);
>        ^
>     TypeError: object is not a function
> ```

The array is like this:

```
var sizes = [{
    "oldName": "10",
    "newName": "10_1",
    "sizeExistsInDest": false,
    "sizeExistsInSrc": false,
    "filesInSrc": [],
    "dirsInDest": [],
    "filesInDest": [],
    "filesToCopy": []
}.....]; //ten or so elements
```

Then I have two functions I'm trying to call in sequence. Like when one is complete, `then`, call the next.

```
var getSrcDirs= function(resolve) {
    async.eachLimit(sizes, 1, function(size, callback){
       var srcDir = path.join(src, size.oldName);
        if (exists(srcDir)){ //exists is from the is-there module
            size.sizeExistsInSrc = true;
        }
        callback();
    }, function(){
        resolve(sizes);
    });
};

var getSrcFiles = function(resolve){
    async.each(sizes, function(size, callback){
        if(size.sizeExistsInSrc){ //only process if the "exists" flag has been set to true
            var fullSrc = path.join(src, size.oldName); //format like 'rootSrc/10'
            fs.readdir(fullSrc, function(err, srcFiles){
                size.filesInSrc = srcFiles;
                callback(); //re-enter each loop once files have been set to `filesInSrc` array
            });
        }else{
            callback(); //if directory doesn't exist, re-enter each loop
        }

    }, function(){
        resolve(sizes);
    });
};

var getFileData = function () {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    getSrcDirs(deferred.resolve);
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

When I call

```
var srcFiles = getFileData()
```

a console print of `srcFiles` shows the modified `sizes` array correctly. However when adding a `then`.

```
var srcFiles = getFileData().then(getSrcFiles);
```

I think I should see files added to the `sizes` array, I get the error I specified above. I'd like to chain a couple more `then`s, but I cannot seem to modify my array more than once.

Comment: Your `getSrcFiles` callback to `.then(…)` will be called with the `sizes` array as its argument, not some `resolve` function!

Comment: The basic mistake I see here is to use promises together with async.js. You should try using only promises.

Comment: Um, that `getSrcDirs` function appears to be synchronous, why are you using callbacks/`async.eachLimit` here?

Comment: @Bergi Several problem. My issue is that the number of files I'm attempting to move is more than node's open file limit. I have tried to use `eachLimit` in order to get around this, but it seemed not to limit the number of files the way I thought it would, as the same errors have persisted. I thought by containing each `each` loop within a segment of a `then` chain, I could compartmentalize their execution, so that I would be sure my reads and writes executed in succession and did not meet with any race condition mishap. Using promises, should the loops be synchronous `forEach`? Or..?

Comment: @Bergi re: your first comment, does this mean I should be using something like `return sizes` rather than `resolve promises`? Thanks for your input.

Comment: What is that `exists` function? Is it actually the asynchronous `fs.exists`?

Comment: No, to fix `getSrcFiles` you should make it take `sizes` as a parameter, and return a promise for the result (not using callbacks)

Comment: @Bergi No that's been deprecated, I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-there

Comment: @Bergi So that's a "no" to the synchronous `forEach`? How would the return of my promise look? When you say "without a callback", where would I return the promise?

Comment: Ah, a wrapper that re-introduced the deprecated function… Still, you are using the synchronous version of `exists`, which you shouldn't.

Comment: A loop with promises is either `reduce` (for sequential execution) or `Promise.all`+`map` (for parallel execution). I'm still searching for the link to point you at

Comment: @Bergi thanks, I look forward to reading it. Would you mind taking a look at my update later? Thanks!

Comment: @bergi, were you able to find the example you were thinking of, or perhaps can you give me an example of how the pattern you describe would work? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24586168/1048572) for some patterns. I think we don't have a canonical yet.