# Promises: Iterating over an array

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I am using Sequelize, which uses Bluebird promises and need to iterate over an array of objects (inserting them one by one - bulkCreate cannot handle duplicate checks on mssql).

It looks something like this:

```
var users = [.....] // Filled up somewhere else.

Product.create(model)
  .then(function() {
      return users;
  })
  .each(function(user) {
      return User.create(......);
  })
```

My question is: Is it ok to return an array of stuff (not promises) like I do in the then?

**EDIT: Another example**

Here is another, better, example of that I was trying to do (with the exception of that this is a setTimeout() instead of a database write). And it looks like it works. It takes each element in the array (two, three, four) and executes the function send to each().

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
function myDelay(who) {
    var deferred = Promise.pending();

    console.log("Starting: " + who);

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Done with: " + who);
        deferred.resolve();         
    }, 250);

    return deferred.promise;
}

myDelay("one")
    .then(function() {
        return ["two", "three", "four"];
    })
    .each(function(who) {
        return myDelay(who);
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log("All done!");
    });
```

It looks to me like it works fine. The output looks like this:

```
Starting: one
Done with: one
Starting: two
Done with: two
Starting: three
Done with: three
Starting: four
Done with: four
All done!
```

with a small delay between each "number".

Comment: What are you trying to achieve - that code looks like it wont work - does it do anything?

Comment: It is pseudocode (kind of)... I want to execute one database insert call per item in the array.

Comment: If you return a value, that is not a Promise from a `then()`, this value will be wrapped with a Promise. So your code wont work in the way, you intent to.

Comment: no wonder it looks broken - look at the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence - there's a paragraph on how to do what you want (I think) in bluebird

Comment: @Sirko - read the comment above yours - it's pseudocode :p

Comment: You're confusing the value returned by `.then`, which is a promise, with the value with which the promise is fulfilled, which is passed as a parameter to `.then` handlers.

Comment: I just added another example in the question that better illustrates what I was trying to achieve. And it looks like it works. But your comments leads me to believe I am still missing something. Or is the each() working differently in bluebird than in other promise libraries?

Comment: if that's what you want, then it's good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it ok to return an array of stuff (not promises) from a `then` callback?

Yes, this is totally fine. The returned promise will then resolve with that callback return value directly, not with the result of some promise. `then` does automatically distinguish promises from non-promises as a part of its assimilation procedure. Your returned `users` array here is no different in that regard from the `undefined` that your last (logging) callback returns.

Your second example is totally fine, only in your first example I'm a bit concerned about the "*filled up somewhere else*" - you should keep that as local as possible. The `users` don't really seem to depend on the result of the `Product.create(model)` promise, so it's a bit odd to have them put in that callback there.