# Run functions that return promises in series after promise is done

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I have an array of functions that I need to execute.
Those functions all return a promise.

I want to run all the functions in series, but the next function can only be started if the promise of the previous function is done.

I thought this would be easy with the async or bluebird library, but I can't find a simple solution to this.

Here is something I made (untested), but I was looking for a standard library solution because this probably already exists?

```
function runFuncs(funcs) {

    function funcRunner(funcs, resolve, reject, pos=0) {
        funcs[pos]().then(function() {
            pos++;
            if (pos < length(funcs)) {
                funcRunner(funcs, pos);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        }).catch(function(err) {
            reject(err);
        });
    }

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        funcRunner(funcs, resolve, reject);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you include `js` that you have tried at Question? And describe what expected and actual result are?

Comment: ^^^^  need some code in order to help you. what @guest271314 said

Comment: @r03 _"Here is something I made (untested), but I was looking for a standard library solution because this probably already exists?"_ Not certain what Question is? Are you seeking a recommendation for a library that uses a pattern similar to `js` at Question?  Can you include `js` contained in `funcs` array at Question?

Comment: Potential answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you've marked an answer already, but I can't comment yet and had to ask: Your example doesn't seem to pass results from one function to another, do you really need them to run in series?

If series is a hard requirement, Bluebird's [`.mapSeries()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html) method will do exactly what you're looking for, and the code is incredibly neat. Otherwise you can swap in [`.map()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) and leverage concurrency to get things done in parallel.

```
Promise.mapSeries(fnArray, (fn) => 
{
    return fn(...);
})
.then((results) =>
{
    // do something with the results.
});
```

Or in parallel with `.map()`:

```
Promise.map(fnArray, (fn) => 
{
    return fn(...);
}, 
{ concurrency: 5 })
.then((results) =>
{
    // do something with the results.
});
```

Comment: yes, the next function may only start when the promise of the previous is done (not just started).

Comment: thanks for the clarification. `.mapSeries` is a good option, if using a library is the way you want to go.

Answer (score 4):

If each of the functions returns a promise itself, you can just chain them together. Something like this should work:

```
function runFuncs(funcs) {
  return funcs.reduce(function (p, funcToRun) {
      return p.then(function () {
        return funcToRun();
      });
  }, Promise.resolve(null));
}
```

Basically, you just keep chaining the promises together. By the nature of the chain, if you return a promise from the `then` handler, that becomes the resulting promise. So the reduce call goes through each promise in the array, doing a `then` on it to process the next one in the array.

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using no additional libraries, just plain old JS code, I was able to come up with a simple solution.

```
'use strict';

// Create an array of functions that return a promise
const promises = [];
let i = 0;
while (i++ < 10) {
  const v = i;
  promises.push(() => {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(v);
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
    });
  });
}

function nextPromise(idx) {
  if (idx >= promises.length) return;
  promises[idx]().then((v) => {
    console.log("Resolved", v);
    nextPromise(++idx);
  });  
}

nextPromise(0);
```

In this example, I created an array of 10 functions, each of which returns a promise which resolves a monotonically increasing number after random number of milliseconds.

To execute them all sequentially, I just use some recursion. It's kind of an ugly bit of hackey looking code, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If "funcs" is array of promises, you can to use Promise.all() - [Promise docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
import {Promise} from 'es6-promise';

const runFuncs = funcs => {
  return Promise.all(funcs);
};

export default runFuncs;
```