# Wait for deep async await results from deep function calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-6

I'm using `async await` via `babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator`.

At the top-level I'm awaiting a function response. Then there another two async functions `func1` and `func2`. `func2` asynchronously retrieves the content of `https://www.google.com`.

The following script returns:

```
go() called
func1() called
finished
func2() called
func2() called
func2() called
```

How can I only `console.log('finished')` after all call are executed successfully? Is it possible without returning them explicitly as `Promise`s using resolve/reject?

*This example is greatly simplified. What I'm trying to do involves recursive function calls I'd to await as well*

```
const rp = require('request-promise')

go()

async function go() {
  console.log("go() called")
  await func1([1,2,3])
  console.log("finished the script")
}

async function func1(arr) {
  console.log("func1() called")
  arr.forEach(async function(element) {
    await func2()
  })
}

async function func2() {
  var res = await rp('https://www.google.com')
  console.log("func2() called")
}
```

Comment: `console.log("finished the script")` does not wait for `await func1([1,2,3])` ? You can alternatively use `Promise.all()`

Comment: Can you have two `await`s in the same function? If yes, probably you have to remove the `async` keyword from inside the `forEach` loop. (I never used async/await)

Comment: @guest271314 In my original code there are recursive function calls involved where one call relies on the result of the former one.

Comment: `Promise.all()` should be able to have recursive calls. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089515/promise-all-inside-a-foreach-loop-everything-firing-at-once,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089515/promise-all-inside-a-foreach-loop-everything-firing-at-once

Comment: There is no "deep" with async/await. You have to return promises from every asynchronous function to be able to `await` it, there is no way around that. Including functions that take asynchronous callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure how to do this for recursive calls but will create a separate question / example for it.

The above example can be fixed by using `for..of` instead of `forEach`. The inner functions results can't be `await`ed.

```
const rp = require('request-promise')

go()

async function go() {
  console.log("go() called")
  await func1([1,2,3])
  console.log("finished the script")
}

async function func1(arr) {
  console.log("func1() called")

  for (let item of arr) {
    await func2()
  }
}

async function func2() {
  var res = await rp('https://www.google.com')
  console.log("func2() called")
}
```