# Control Which Code Stops with Async/Await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, ecmascript-2017

Can you stop code outside of the `async` function using `await`? However, I don't want all code to stop. I want to control what code will run.

I think there might be a solution, something like this:

```
var isAsyncRunning = false;
var currentPromise;
async function asyncFunc(){
    isAsyncRunning = true;
    //Do some code here
    currentPromise = promise; //promise was defined inside the code
    await promise;
    promise.then(function(){
        isAsyncRunning = false;
    });
}
async function anotherFunction(){
    if(!isAsyncRunning){
        await currentPromise;
    }
    //Do some other code here
}
```

However, I have a lot of functions and don't want to apply this to *every single function* that I have.

Is there a better solution? If not, is there anything I can do to make this less time-consuming?

Comment: What applying this to every single function accomplish? Some background or example might help.

Comment: Not every single function. I said to *control* what it stops, not apply it to all of the functions.

Comment: you can't use `await` inside a function that isn't set as `async` - so `anotherFunction` is invalid

Comment: @JaromandaX Oh yes, forgot about that. Fixed!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? If you want to run promises in sequence you can use `reduce` function in `bluebird` or if you prefer vanilla javascript use this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36672042/177006

Comment: I don't want to run promises in sequence. I want to pause some code, but control which code is paused using `await`.

Comment: @MasterBob Forget `await` for a moment. What problem are you trying to solve, and what behavior do you expect? You can't arbitrarily "pause" or "stop" code in JS. JS doesn't have threads (web workers aside).

Comment: @jib If almost everyone is not going to get what the question is about, here's an example: `prompt`. `prompt` stops all code _except_ for the user typing. I want to implement something like that, but I want to control which I stop and which I keep running,

Comment: @MasterBob: after your latest comment, I updated my answer with a new section. Hopefully that answer your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your understanding of Promises and `async/await` is not correct. When you make a function `async`, the `await` keyword before a promise make sure that code execution will pause until the promise fulfilled or rejected. Your code can be simplified:

```
var currentPromise;

async function asyncFunc(promise){
    // Do some code here
    return await promise;
}

function anotherFunction(){
    asyncFunc(currentPromise);
}
```

When we are calling `return await promise`, the execution engine waits in a non-blocking way until the promise fulfilled or rejected, and then it returns the output to the `anotherFunction` function.

**Note:** If you want to run promises in a sequence you can use `reduce` function in `bluebird` or this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36672042/177006), if you prefer vanilla javascript.

## Pausing code execution

From your latest comment to the original question, I understand that you want to pause the execution of your program. First, you need to understand that **stopping the Javascript execution in a blocking way is not possible.** Javascript is a single-threaded programming language that uses event loop to handle concurrency. You can never stop the entire engine for an operation. Otherwise, the program will freeze. In a thread-based programming language, programmers use threads to implement concurrency.

In Javascript, however, you can pause the execution in a **non-blocking way** using `async / await`. For example:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

async function main() {
  await sleep(1500)
  console.log('Hello world with delay!')
}

main()
```

If I understand correctly, in your case you'd like to pause the execution based on a user input. You can implement any type of logic that you want. For example, the following program wait for the user to press the `RETURN` key:

```
function waitForUserInput(keyCode) {
  return new Promise(resolve => 
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      if (event.keyCode === keyCode) resolve()
    }
  )
}

async function main() {
  await waitForUserInput(13)
  console.log('Thank you for your submission!')
}

main()
```

In this example, the promise will not be resolved until the `keyCode` is pressed, and nothing will be logged into the console. Note, that `waitForUserInput` will not stop the Javascript engine. The engine will continue executing any other code and respond to UI events.

Comment: I know how it works, but I'm looking at your last line. "The engine will continue executing any other code and respond to UI events." I want to control if this code runs, or that code runs, or what.

Comment: @MasterBob You can do that by *await*, but you cannot pause the Javascript engine altogether. It is impossible! Please invest some time and read this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop Also, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2734311/177006

Comment: I guess it is impossible then, and I will have to use my solution. This worries me, because now even regular functions will not work on browsers which do not support `async`/`await`.

Comment: @MasterBob: If you use `Babel` to transpile your code to ES5, all `async / await` will be converted to Promises and will work on all browsers. Check this out: http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=latest%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=function%20sleep(ms)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20setTimeout(resolve%2C%20ms))%0A%7D%0A%0Aasync%20function%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20await%20sleep(1500)%0A%20%20console.log('Hello%20world%20with%20delay!')%0A%7D&playground=true

Comment: @MasterBob I am suspecting there is a structural problem with what you have in mind. Create a new question with the specific use case and ask for a structural answer. Pretty sure what you want to do is possible with Javascript if architectured correctly!