# Creating a promise chain in a for loop

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I would expect the code below to print one number on the console, then wait a second and then print another number. Instead, it prints all 10 numbers immediately and then waits ten seconds. What is the correct way to create a promise chain that behaves as described?

```
function getProm(v) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log(v);
        resolve();
    })
}

function Wait() {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000))
}

function createChain() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
    let chain = Promise.resolve();
    for (let i of a) {
        chain.then(()=>getProm(i))
            .then(Wait)

    }
    return chain;
}


createChain();
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to assign the return value of `.then` back to `chain`:

```
chain = chain.then(()=>getProm(i))
         .then(Wait)
```

Now you will basically be doing

```
chain
  .then(()=>getProm(1))
  .then(Wait)
  .then(()=>getProm(2))
  .then(Wait)
  .then(()=>getProm(3))
  .then(Wait)
  // ...
```

instead of

```
chain
  .then(()=>getProm(1))
  .then(Wait)

chain
  .then(()=>getProm(2))
  .then(Wait)

chain
  .then(()=>getProm(3))
  .then(Wait)
// ...
```

You can see that the first one is actually a chain, while the second one is parallel.

Comment: Mind looking at my problem?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856376/break-a-promise-chain-inside-for-loop

Answer (score 2):

See [Resolve promises one after another (i.e. in sequence)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence).

Using `i of a`:

```
function createChain() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
    let chain = Promise.resolve();
    for (let i of a) {
        chain = chain.then(()=>getProm(i))
            .then(Wait)
    }
    return chain;
}
```

Using `a.forEach()`

```
function createChain() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
    let chain = Promise.resolve();
    a.forEach(i =>
        chain = chain.then(()=>getProm(i))
            .then(Wait)
    );
    return chain;
}
```

Using `a.reduce()`

```
function createChain() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
    return a.reduce((chain, i) =>
        chain.then(()=>getProm(i))
            .then(Wait),
        Promise.resolve()
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Now that we have `await`/`async`, a better way to do this is:

```
function getProm(v) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log(v);
        resolve();
    })
}

function Wait() {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000))
}

async function createChain() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
    for (let i of a) {
        await getProm(i);
        await Wait();
    }
}


createChain();
```

Comment: This is not a better way at all, because it is discouraged to use await inside a for loop. Internally the await syntax is just a helper for the engine which 'rewrites' the subsequent code (beyond the await keyword) as though it were wrapped in a "then". The program can't "continue" the for loop, after it has handed back the execution control to the event scheduler. In short: NEVER use await inside a for loop.

Comment: @Gabriel ops specifically wants a sequential execution, this answer works and does just that. Although it is true await/async is discouraged inside loops (because you loose parallelism https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-await-in-loop) in the context of answering the actual question we don't care. I don't agree with the downvotes: the answer is correct. I don't understand where you got that "NEVER use await inside loops" -> as you said this is merely syntactic sugar and the standard allows it for a reason...

Comment: I think that the question is about creating a promise chain, not necessarily about executing it right now. Also, six years ago, at the time of the question, an await inside a loop was, indeed, discouraged by the JS documentation as far as I remember. It is different now in 2023.