# Break a Promise chain inside for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, es6-promise

I am working on a promise chain that was inspired by this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44955506/7485805

I want to break this for loop in order to properly handle the rejection of the chain. I just figured that I can't use `break` inside the `.catch` method of the chain.

Here's my code if it helps:

```
function pro (arr) {
  let chain = Promise.resolve();
  const self = {req: {}, res: {}};
  const length = arr.length;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for(let i=0; i<length; i++){
      chain = chain
          .then(() => arr[i].call(self) )
          .then(() => {
            if(i === (length - 1) )
              resolve();
          })
          .catch(e => {
            reject(e);
          })
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    return self
  })
  .catch(e => {
    throw new Error (e);
  })

}

const x = function () {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    self.req = {key: "value"}
    resolve();
  })  
}

const y =  function () {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(self);
    reject();
  })
}

const z = function () {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('failed');
  })
}



pro([x, y, z])
.then((self) => {
  console.log('final',self);
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log('error', e);
})
```

`x, y, z` are three functions chained together in function `pro`
While, `x` resolves successfully, `y` is executed but gets rejected.

I want to stop the execution of `z` since it's pointless to continue and may produce error in actual code.

Also, if someone can recommend me a better version for this piece of code:

```
.then(() => {
  if(i === (length - 1) )
    resolve();
})
```

Note: I cannot use `await` since this code will be executed server-side and use of `await` may block other incoming requests.

Comment: _"I want to break this for loop"_ See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48349837/) at [Run multiple recursive Promises and break when requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349721/run-multiple-recursive-promises-and-break-when-requested). Why does the loop need to be broken to handle an error? What does _"break"_ mean within the context?

Comment: @Bergi Please check the link: https://www.es6console.com/jsjdb5rx/

Comment: "*y is executed but gets rejected, I want to stop the execution of z*" - uh, if you've built your chain in the same way as in the answer you linked, then `z` doesn't get executed at all?! Your problem is that `.catch(e => {
            reject(e);
          })` which doesn't actually handle the error

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424853/) what what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much easier to do with the `async/await` syntax:

```
async function pro(arr) {
    const self = {req: {}, res: {}};
    for(const f of arr) await f.call(self);
    return self;
}
```

```js
async function pro(arr) {
    const self = {req: {}, res: {}};
    for(const f of arr) await f.call(self);
    return self;
}

const x = function () {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    self.req = {key: "value"}
    resolve();
  })  
}

const y =  function () {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(self);
    reject("y failed");
  })
}

const z = function () {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   console.log('failed');
  })
}

pro([x, y, z]).then((self) => {
  console.log('final',self);
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log('error', e);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure using `await` won't block other incoming request on node server?

Comment: No, `await` is [not blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44410481/5459839). It makes the function *return* immediately with a promise. Its context is restored when that promise resolves.

Answer (score 2):

A few things: when you construct your promise chain inside of a for loop, that's all that happens: the chain is constructed. The `.then` execution will happen at the earliest in the next event loop. I'll try to illustrate:

```
var promiseChain = functionReturningPromise();
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
  promiseChain = promiseChain.then(x=> {
    return anotherPromiseFunction(x);
  });
}
```

Depending on what `functionReturningPromise` actually does, something may have already happened at this point...or maybe not. For example we may have started a `fetch`, or maybe started up a `WebWorker.` However if we had a `setTimeout` nested inside of the first Promise, then all we did was put the `setTimeout` callback into the queue for the next cycle of the event loop. But guaranteed 100%, no `.then` functions have run yet. That comes later, in the next event loop.

So next event loop comes, and the promise has resolved. That means the next `.then` will get run. Let's say it fails. At that point, because we chained the promises (`promiseChain = promiseChain.then`), we immediately skip to the first `.catch` (or `.then` with a second parameter) in the chain, and all intervening `.then`s get completely skipped without being executed. Or if there are no `catch`es, then this promise chain is done. No break necessary; it's just how Promises work.

So if you just add a `.catch` at the very end of the chain, you're good.

About this "event loop" thing: I **really** recommend watching [Jake Archibald: In The Loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0), from JSConf.Asia 2018.

Also about `await`...Sounds as if there is some confusion about how it works. You can only use `await` **inside** an `async` function, so you can never completely block thread execution with a single `await`. It works just like chaining `.then`s, just syntactic sugar. So @trincot is definitely right, you're going to be much happier with that syntax.

Comment: I really love the explanation here. Thanks a lot. 
Also, You just cleared my doubts on `await` and I'll definitely watch JSConf link.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative answer that just executes the promises in succession unless a promise was rejected which is then stopped. This doesn't use await but it should give you a general idea how it could be done without it but this code was also written very quickly so it's not the most optimised code.

```js
const x = function() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve('it resolved ma!');
  });
};

const y = function() {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject("reject");
  });
};

const z = function() {
  const self = this;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("never gets executed");
  });
};

function runPromises(promises) {
  const results = [];
  let count = 0;
  const executePromise = i => {
    count++;
    return promises[i]()
      .then((response) => {
        results.push(response);
        if (count !== promises.length) {
          executePromise(count);
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        results.push(e);
        console.log("stop right now, thank you very much");
      });
  };
  if (Array.isArray(promises)) {
    executePromise(count);
  }
  return results;
}

const results = runPromises([x, y, z]);
console.log(results);
```