# Vue JS Promise Sequential vs Parallel

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, vue.js

I have working code in VueJS however need a certain block to run sequentially:

```
  return Promise.all(this.vm.multipleActions.run.map(function (testRun) {
    return self.initiateTest(testRun);
  }))
```

Currently it seems this runs in parallel - so in initiateTest() I insert records into a DB however parallel gets me random ordering instead of the testRuns in order (which I'd like to preserve).

I can observe the AJAX calls in initiateTest() made randomly due to the parallel nature.

Comment: Can you udate the question with what you want to be executed before this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve promises one after another (i.e. in sequence)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the results of `self.initiateTest(testRun)` in the returned promise like your code does with `Promise.all`, you can use array reduce function like so

```
return this.vm.multipleActions.run.reduce((promise, testRun) =>
    promise.then(results => 
        self.initiateTest(testRun).then(result => {
            results.push(result);
            return results;
        })
    ), Promise.resolve([]) // initial promise to chain to
);
```

Note: if using arrow functions, the `self.initiateTest` could possibly be `this.initiateTest` - though, it's not clear what `self` is in your code

The returned promise will resolve to an array of (resolved) results returned by `self.initiateTest(testRun)`

the non ES2015+ version of the above code is

```
return this.vm.multipleActions.run.reduce(function (promise, testRun) {
    return promise.then(function (results) {
        return self.initiateTest(testRun).then(function (result) {
            results.push(result);
            return results;
        });
    });
}, Promise.resolve([]));
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the them to run sequentially, you need to call `initiateTest` once the previous test has completed.

```
var promise = Promise.resolve();
this.vm.multipleActions.run.forEach(function (testRun) {
    promise = promise.then(function() {
        return self.initiateTest(testRun);
    });
})
return promise;
```

This code will create an initial promise that is resolved immediately. Each test run is attached to the promise's then handler, so they only execute once the previous promise has been resolved.

Or to shorten it even further, you can use `reduce`:

```
return this.vm.multipleActions.run.reduce(function (promise, testRun) {
    return promise.then(function() {
        return self.initiateTest(testRun);
    });
}, Promise.resolve())
```