# Node js Puppeteer goto array of pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I try to go page by page from my array, but get this:

> (node:4196) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 request listeners added. Use
>    emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
>   (node:4196) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 framedetached listeners adde
>   d. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
>   (node:4196) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 lifecycleevent listeners add
>   ed. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
>   (node:4196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Target closed.
>       at Promise (D:\Kutz\irrParse\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:198:56)
>       at new Promise ()
>       at CDPSession.send (D:\Kutz\irrParse\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Connection.js:197:12)
>       at navigate (D:\Kutz\irrParse\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:520:39)
>       at Page.goto (D:\Kutz\irrParse\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:500:7)
>       at uniqueLinks.forEach (D:\Kutz\irrParse\scrape.js:26:16)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at D:\Kutz\irrParse\scrape.js:25:15
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
>   (node:4196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing
>   inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (r
>   ejection id: 1)
>   (node:4196) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise reject
>   ions that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
>   (node:4196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
>       at Promise.then (D:\Kutz\irrParse\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\NavigatorWatcher.js:71:21)
>       at

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
var forEach = require('async-foreach').forEach;


const url = "https://reddit.com/r/programming";
const linkSelector = ".content a.title";

(async () => {
  // Launch chrome process
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "load" });

  // This runs the `document.querySelectorAll` within the page and passes
  // the result to function
  const links = await page.$$eval(linkSelector, links => {
    return links.map((link) => link.href);
  });

  // Make sure we get the unique set of links only
  const uniqueLinks = [...links];
  //console.log(uniqueLinks[0]);

  uniqueLinks.forEach(async (link) => {
    await page.goto(link, { waitUntil: "load" });
  });

  // Kill the browser process
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Error throws in forEach()

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? Hitting the issue today, too.

Comment: Nothing to do with `Array.prototype.forEach`, it's answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768444/possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: See also [Crawling multiple URLs in a loop using Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293216/crawling-multiple-urls-in-a-loop-using-puppeteer/65000065#65000065)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, `Array.prototype.forEach`'s iterator function is not executed in an async manner as you would expect when defining it as async. Using a for loop should work for what you're trying to do.

```
for (let i = 0; i < uniqueLinks.length; i ++) {
  await page.goto(uniqueLinks[i], { waitUntil: "load" });
}
```