# Scraping multiple URLs one by one with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape multiple URL one by one, then repeat the scrape after one minute.

But I keep getting two errors and was hoping for some help.

I got an error saying:

> functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics

And I get this error when I run the function / code:

```
TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded.
```

My code:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const urls = [
  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cw9FIeHbdB8',
  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imy1px59abE',
  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ'
];

const scrape = async() => {
  let browser, page;

  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    page = await browser.newPage();

    for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
      const url = urls[i];
      await page.goto(`${url}`);
      await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

      await page.waitForSelector('.view-count', { visible: true, timeout: 60000 });

      const data = await page.evaluate(() => { // functions declared within loops referencing an outer scoped on this line.
        return [
          JSON.stringify(document.querySelector('#text > a').innerText),
          JSON.stringify(document.querySelector('#container > h1').innerText),
          JSON.stringify(document.querySelector('.view-count').innerText),
          JSON.stringify(document.querySelector('#owner-sub-count').innerText)
        ];
      });

      const [channel, title, views, subs] = [JSON.parse(data[0]), JSON.parse(data[1]), JSON.parse(data[2]), JSON.parse(data[3])];
      console.log({ channel, title, views, subs });
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } finally {
    if (browser) {
      await browser.close();
    }
    await setTimeout(scrape, 60000); // repeat after one minute after all urls have been scrape.
  }
};

scrape();
```

I would really appreciate any help I could get.

Answer (score 1):

This works. Putting the for loop in a Promise and `waitUntil: "networkidle2"` as an option when `page.goto()` resolves your problem. You don't need to generate a new browser each time, so it should be declared outside of the for loop.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const urls = [
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cw9FIeHbdB8",
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imy1px59abE",
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ",
];

const scrape = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    for (url of urls) {
      // your timeout
      await page.waitForTimeout(6 * 1000);

      await page.goto(`${url}`, {
        waitUntil: "networkidle2",
        timeout: 60 * 1000,
      });

      await page.waitForSelector(".view-count", {
        waitUntil: "networkidle2",
        timeout: 60 * 1000,
      });

      const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return [
          JSON.stringify(document.querySelector("#text > a").innerText),
          JSON.stringify(document.querySelector("#container > h1").innerText),
          JSON.stringify(document.querySelector(".view-count").innerText),
          JSON.stringify(document.querySelector("#owner-sub-count").innerText),
        ];
      });

      const [channel, title, views, subs] = [
        JSON.parse(data[0]),
        JSON.parse(data[1]),
        JSON.parse(data[2]),
        JSON.parse(data[3]),
      ];
      console.log({ channel, title, views, subs });
    }
    resolve(true);
  })
    .then(async () => {
      await browser.close();
    })
    .catch((reason) => {
      console.log(reason);
    });
};

scrape();
```

**#Update**
As per ggorlen suggestion, the below-refactored code should serve your problem. Comment in the code indicates the purpose of that line

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const urls = [
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cw9FIeHbdB8",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imy1px59abE",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ",
];

const scrape = async () => {
    // generate a headless browser instance
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });

    // used .entries to get the index and value
    for (const [index, url] of urls.entries()) {

        // generating a new page for each of the content
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        // your 60 timeout from 2nd index
        if (index > 0) await page.waitForTimeout(60 * 1000);

        // wait for the page response to available with 60 seconds timeout (error throw)
        await page.goto(`${url}`, {
            waitUntil: "networkidle2",
            timeout: 60 * 1000,
        });

        // wait for .view-count section to be available
        await page.waitForSelector(".view-count");

        // don't need json stringify or parse as puppeteer does so
        await page.evaluate(() =>
        ({
            channel: document.querySelector("#text > a").innerText,
            title: document.querySelector("#container > h1").innerText,
            views: document.querySelector(".view-count").innerText,
            subs: document.querySelector("#owner-sub-count").innerText
        })
        ).then(data => {
            // your scrapped success data
            console.log('response', data);
        }).catch(reason => {
            // your scrapping error reason
            console.log('error', reason);
        }).finally(async () => {
            // close your current page
            await page.close();
        })
    }

    // after looping through finally close the browser
    await browser.close();
};

scrape();
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help but. 

I just tried to add finally block after catch block but i sometimes get an error if `data` returns back undefined and then the finally block is not called.
Would you know anyway to fix that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is the right idea but the `JSON.stringify`/`parse` calls and `new Promise` aren't needed. ``${url}`` -> `url`, `then(async () => {` should be `.finally(() => browser?.close())` so it runs even if there's a throw, this only waits 6 seconds, not 60 seconds, and a few other minor nitpicks. Welcome to SO!

Comment: @ggorlen I replaced the `then` with a `finally` after catch block but it ends up not calling the finally block if it throws an error. Would you know the reason why this is happening?

Comment: Seems like that should be OK -- I'd have to see the code.

Comment: @ggorlen updated code should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a design like this:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.4.1
const {setTimeout} = require("node:timers/promises");

const scrapeTextSelectors = async (browser, url, textSelectors) => {
  let page;

  try {
    page = await browser.newPage();
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(50 * 1000);
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
    const dataPromises = textSelectors.map(async ({name, sel}) => {
      await page.waitForSelector(sel);
      return [name, await page.$eval(sel, e => e.innerText)];
    });
    return Object.fromEntries(await Promise.all(dataPromises));
  }
  finally {
    await page?.close();
  }
};

const urls = [
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cw9FIeHbdB8",
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imy1px59abE",
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ",
];
const textSelectors = [
  {name: "channel", sel: "#text > a"},
  {name: "title", sel: "#container > h1"},
  {name: "views", sel: ".view-count"},
  {name: "subs", sel: "#owner-sub-count"},
];

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});

  for (;; await setTimeout(60_000)) {
    const data = await Promise.allSettled(urls.map(url =>
      scrapeTextSelectors(browser, url, textSelectors)
    ));
    console.log(data);
  }
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

A few remarks:

- This runs in parallel on the 3 URLs using [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled). If you have more URLs, you'll want a task queue or run synchronously over the URLs with a `for .. of` loop so you don't outstrip the system's resources. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65000065/6243352) for elaboration.
- I use `waitForSelector` on each and every selector rather than just `'.view-count'` so you won't miss anything.
- `page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(60_000);` gives you an adjustable 50-second delay on all operations.
- Moving the loops to sleep and step over the URLs into the caller gives cleaner, more flexible code. Generally, if a function can operate on a single element rather than a collection, it should.
- Error handling is improved; `Promise.allSettled` lets the caller control what to do if any requests fail. You might want to filter and/or map the `data` response to remove the statuses: `data.map(({value}) => value)`.
- Generally, `return` instead of `console.log` data to keep functions flexible. The caller can `console.log` in the format they desire, if they desire.
- There's no need to do anything special in `page.goto(url)` because we're awaiting selectors on the very next line. `"networkidle2"` just slows things down, waiting for network requests that might not impact the selectors we're interested in.
- `JSON.stringify`/`JSON.parse` is already called by Puppeteer on the return value of `evaluate` so you can skip it in most cases.
- Generally, don't do anything but cleanup in `finally` blocks. `await setTimeout(scrape, 60000)` is misplaced.

Comment: I have a question what's with the question mark on page?.close and browser?.close. Is that a spelling mistake or am i missing something here?

Comment: It's called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). It's shorthand for roughly `page && page.close()` or `if (page) page.close()`. It's possible that a throw happens before the `page` or `browser` object are defined, so we don't want to attempt calling `undefined.close()` under these circumstances.

Comment: Oh ok i have never seen that done before. Thanks for the information and link!