# Navigation Timeout issue in Node JS Puppeteer Core

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm relatively new to web scraping and currently working on a project to extract laptop specifications from [this site](https://www.bhphotovideo.com).

Despite some success, I have been somewhat successful with scraping this page but facing intermittent timeout errors like this: `TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded`.

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    // Initialize puppeteer
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    // Scrape the landing page for each manufacturer page for links to a single device page
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
    const selector = 'a[data-selenium="miniProductPageProductNameLink"]';
    await page.waitForSelector(selector);

    const laptopLinks = await page.$$eval(selector, (links) =>
      links.map((link) => link.href)
    );
    // The section above works 100% of the time. Never failed once.

    // Looping through the links scraped above
    let specsArray = [];
    const specSelector = ".group_fDXOr6EpR9";

    for (let i = 0; i < laptopLinks.length; i++) {
      // Open the page
      try {
        const link = laptopLinks[i];

        // Go to the specs page
        await page.goto(`${link}\specs`, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });

        await page.waitForSelector(specSelector);

        // Extract the HTML of the specs section
        const specsHTML = await page.$$eval(specSelector, (element) => {
          return element.map((el) => el.innerHTML).join("");
        });

        // Grab the title of the
        const title = await page.$eval(
          'h1[data-selenium="productTitle"]',
          (element) => element.textContent.trim()
        );

        await page.goBack();

        // parseHTML is an helper function I use to extract the content of the HTML I need
        // and return an object.
        specsArray.push(await parseHTML(specsHTML, title));

        // Save to the database using a Helper function.
        await saveToDatabase(specsArray, "Dell");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(
          `Error occurred during scraping laptop ${i + 1}: ${error}`
        );
        return;
      }
    }
    // close the browser
    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

The code fails consistently after a few loop on the `await page.waitForSelector(specSelector)` line.

Is there something wrong with my approach? Or how can I best achieve this operation? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

Edit #1. I made some changes to my code, thanks to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68850426/10864570) I stumbled on:

```js
const urls = [
   // ...pages per laptop filter 
]

const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const scrapeBHPhotoVideo = async () => {

  // Initialize Puppeteer connect

  const allLinks = [];

  for (const [index, url] of urls.entries()) {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(2 * 60 * 1000);
    await delay(5000); // 5 seconds delay

    try {
      await page.goto(`${url}`, {
        waitUntil: "networkidle2",
        timeout: 60 * 1000,
      });

      if (index > 0) {
        await page.waitForSelector(
          'a[data-selenium="miniProductPageProductNameLink"]',
          {
            waitUntil: "networkidle2",
            timeout: 60 * 1000,
          }
        );
      }

      console.log(`Navigating to ${url}`);

      const { status } = await client.send("Captcha.solve", {
        detectTimeout: 30 * 1000,
      });
      console.log(`Captcha solve status: ${status}`);

      console.log("Taking screenshot to page.png");

      await page.screenshot({ path: "./page.png", fullPage: true });

      console.log("Navigated! Scraping page content...");

      const links = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return [
          ...document.querySelectorAll(
            'a[data-selenium="miniProductPageProductNameLink"]'
          ),
        ].map((link) => link.href);
      });

      console.log(links);

      allLinks.push(...links);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`Error occurred during navigating to ${url}: ${err}`);
    } finally {
      await page.close();
    }
  }

  for (const [index, link] of allLinks.entries()) {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(2 * 60 * 1000);
    await delay(5000); // 5 seconds delay

    try {
      await page.goto(`${link}/specs`, {
        waitUntil: "networkidle2",
        timeout: 60 * 1000,
      });

      if (index > 0) {
        await page.waitForSelector("tr.pair_KqJ3Q3GPKv", {
          waitUntil: "networkidle2",
          timeout: 60 * 1000,
        });
      }

      const { status } = await client.send("Captcha.solve", {
        detectTimeout: 30 * 1000,
      });
      console.log(`Captcha solve status: ${status}`);

      const specs = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const specs = {
          laptopbrand: document.querySelector(
            'h1[data-selenium="productTitle"]'
          ).innerText,
          processor: document.querySelector,
          cpu: "",
          gpu: "",
          graphics_type: "",
          ram: "",
          storage: "",
          display: "",
          resolution: "",
          refresh_rate: "",
          panel_type: "",
          built_in_speaker: "",
          built_in_microphone: "",
          network_io: "",
          usb_ports: "",
          webcam: "",
          cellular: "",
          bluetooth: "",
          wifi: "",
          battery: "",
          dimension: "",
          weight: "",
        };
        const rows = document.querySelectorAll("tr.pair_KqJ3Q3GPKv");

        rows.forEach((el) => {
          const label = el
            .querySelector("td.label_KqJ3Q3GPKv")
            .textContent.trim();
          const value = el
            .querySelector("td.value_KqJ3Q3GPKv span:not(.notSpecfMon)")
            .textContent.trim();

          // Map label to the corresponding property in the specs object
          switch (label) {
            case "Processor":
              specs.processor = value;
              break;
            case "CPU":
              specs.cpu = value;
              break;
            case "GPU":
              specs.gpu = value;
              break;
            case "Graphics Type":
              specs.graphics_type = value;
              break;
            case "Total Installed Memory":
              specs.ram = value;
              break;
            case "Total Installed Capacity":
              specs.storage = value;
              break;
            case "Display Size":
              specs.display = value;
              break;
            case "Resolution":
              specs.resolution = value;
              break;
            case "Refresh Rate":
              specs.refresh_rate = value;
              break;
            case "Panel Type":
              specs.panel_type = value;
              break;
            case "Built-In Speakers":
              specs.built_in_speaker = value;
              break;
            case "Built-In Microphones":
              specs.built_in_microphone = value;
              break;
            case "Network I/O":
              specs.network_io = value;
              break;
            case "Inputs/Outputs":
              specs.usb_ports = value;
              break;
            case "Webcam":
              specs.webcam = value;
              break;
            case "Cellular Support":
              specs.cellular = value;
              break;
            case "Bluetooth":
              specs.bluetooth = value;
              break;
            case "Wi-Fi":
              specs.wifi = value;
              break;
            case "Capacity":
              specs.battery = value;
              break;
            case "Dimensions":
              specs.dimension = value;
              break;
            case "Weight":
              specs.weight = value;
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        });

        return specs;
      });

      console.log(specs);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`Error occurred during navigating to ${link}: ${err}`);
    } finally {
      await page.close();
    }
  }

  await browser.close();
};

scrapeBHPhotoVideo();
```

**Sample Output:**

```bash
{
  laptopbrand: 'Dell 14" Latitude 3440 Multi-Touch Notebook',
  processor: 'Intel Core i7-1355U (13th Gen)',
  cpu: '10-Core: Up to 5 GHz Performance (2 Cores)Up to 3.7 GHz Efficiency (8 Cores)',
  gpu: 'Intel Iris Xe',
  graphics_type: 'Integrated',
  ram: '16 GB',
  storage: '512 GB',
  display: '14"',
  resolution: '1920 x 1080',
  refresh_rate: '60 Hz',
  panel_type: 'IPS-Type LCD',
  built_in_speaker: 'Yes',
  built_in_microphone: 'Yes',
  network_io: '1 x RJ45 (Gigabit Ethernet)',
  usb_ports: '1 x USB-C 3.1/3.2 Gen 2 / Supports Video Alt Mode and Power Delivery3 x USB-A 3.0 / 3.1/3.2 Gen 1',
  webcam: 'User-Facing:',
  cellular: 'No',
  bluetooth: 'Yes',
  wifi: 'Wi-Fi 6E (802.11ax) with MU-MIMO Support (2 x 2)',
  battery: '3-Cell: 54 Wh',
  dimension: '12.7 x 8.6 x 0.73" / 32.3 x 21.8 x 1.85 cm',
  weight: '3.42 lb / 1.55 kg'
}

file:///home/cfcife/work/scrape-bhphoto/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:92
    #error = new ProtocolError();
             ^

ProtocolError: Target.attachToTarget timed out. Increase the 'protocolTimeout' setting in launch/connect calls for a higher timeout if needed.
    at <instance_members_initializer> (file:///home/cfcife/work/scrape-bhphoto/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:92:14)
    at new Callback (file:///home/cfcife/work/scrape-bhphoto/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:96:16)
    at CallbackRegistry.create (file:///home/cfcife/work/scrape-bhphoto/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/CallbackRegistry.js:29:26)
    at Connection._rawSend (file:///home/cfcife/work/scrape-bhphoto/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/cdp/Connection.js:88:26)
    at Connection.send (file:///home/cfcife/work/scrape-bhphoto/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/cdp/Connection.js:82:21)
    at Connection._createSession (file:///home/cfcife/work/scrape-bhphoto/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/cdp/Connection.js:187:42)
    at PageTarget.createSession (file:///home/cfcife/work/scrape-bhphoto/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/cdp/Browser.js:138:37)
    at PageTarget.createCDPSession (file:///home/cfcife/work/scrape-bhphoto/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/cdp/Target.js:75:36)
    at scrapeBHPhotoVideo (file:///home/cfcife/work/scrape-bhphoto/scrape-bhphoto.js:87:40)
```

Scraped 18/28 before showing this error.

Comment: I don't see any results for `a[data-selenium="miniProductPageProductNameLink"]` or `.group_fDXOr6EpR9` on the page you gave. Are you sure that's the right URL?

Comment: @ggorlen the flow is scrape this [url](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/products/laptops/ci/18818/N/4110474292/pn/6?sort=BEST_SELLERS&filters=fct_brand_name%3Adell) filtered by brand. Then for [each laptop](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1787785-REG/dell_mcthc_13_4_xps_13_9315.html) parse the specs.

Comment: I have made progress using the answer in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68843938/puppeteer-scraping-multiple-urls-one-by-one) . I noticed I do not close the page on every loop and I am better off initializing a new page for each loop and closing it after. The success rate far better, but still trying to resolve a new error I got on my 2nd try - `ProtocolError: Target.attachToTarget timed out. Increase the 'protocolTimeout' setting in launch/connect calls for a higher timeout if needed.` @ggorlen

Comment: @ggorlen thank you. Check the edit to the question

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)