# Puppeteer page.on loaded evaluate

Tags: puppeteer

How do you properly pass the puppeteer page to the page.on('load' or page.on('domontentloaded events?

```js
do{
  var page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('domcontentloaded', async () => {
    page.evaluate(() => {
      console.log('do something');
    });
  });
  page.goto( etc... , {'waitUntil':'load'}
}
```

I have written this as basic as possible in a do{ } loop to show that the variable page will be recreated constantly over and over.

This scenerio "seems" to work on most occasions, but I believe this is causing unexpected results in my application.

Here is the type of code i'm looking for:

```js
var page = await browser.newPage();
page.on('domcontentloaded', async (this) => {
  this.evaluate(() => {
    console.log('do something');
  });
});
```

Can anybody help?

https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.pageeventobject

Or is this not possible in any way? (it says Type: Never)

If not: How can I get the "browser page" from the page.on event ? Is the only way to use the first declared var? If so, won't there be unexpected results the faster things go?

UPDATE CODE BELOW TO SHOW HOW TO RUN page.evaluate on comcontentloaded and still wait for page load.

```js
var page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto( etc... , {'waitUntil':'domcontentloaded'});
await page.evaluate(() => {
  console.log('do something');
});
await page.waitForNetworkIdle({idleTime: 100})'
...
```

Is this the best way to run javascript as quickly as possible after domcontentloaded ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This is a rather unusual pattern that I don't understand your motivation for wanting to use. Sharing the actual site you're working with and stating your high-level objective on that site would help, because there's [likely a better way to achieve whatever you're trying to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). You're not `await`ing `page.evaluate()` so that's almost certainly a race condition. Your `page.goto` call already waits for the load event, so there's normally no reason to use `page.on("load"`.

Comment: I am trying to run javascript on the page load event. There is not 1 website i'm trying to do this for but many. I want to run a small bit of javascript on every page domcontentloaded (to make page loading faster), but in my page.goto(url i am using 'waitUntil':'load'

Comment: All right, then it sounds like my above tip applies--just put the code you want to run on load directly after the `await page.goto()` line and you're done. `page` is your hook into just about everything. There's no need for a `this` or callback here as far as I can see, and I've never seen a practical application for putting `page.evaluate()` inside a `page.on("load"` callback. If you think this pattern does make sense for your use case, I'd need more context before I agree or can recommend a different solution.

Comment: Thank you! I have updated my question to show your answer. I will try this and hope for better results. Thank you again!

Comment: The `waitForNavigation` is unnecessary in your update. Remove that and you have a normal-looking Puppeteer script. Is it suitable for your task? Probably, but I can't say for sure because I don't know what your goal is.

Comment: I don't need to wait for 'load' after only waiting for 'domcontentloaded' ?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. Normally, no. If you did, then you'd change your release condition on `goto()` to `{waitUntil: "load"}`, which happens to be the default. [This](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#never-using-domcontentloaded) explains all of the load conditions. Usually, pick one, whichever is the least strict way to achieve your goal. If the goal is to scrape data from one element, say, a table, usually `domcontentloaded` + `waitForSelector()` is the ideal pattern. `waitForNavigation()` is seldom necessary and often overused.

Comment: I see, probably everything that is not normal. HAHA. I will test both ways, Thanks again.

Comment: Also important: use `const` rather than `var` to ensure your `page` is scoped to the loop block rather than function-scoped, which could result in shared state bugs. [Crawling multiple URLs in a loop using Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293216/crawling-multiple-urls-in-a-loop-using-puppeteer/65000065#65000065) may also help.

Comment: Thanks! I will see if that helps as well. The page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'load' }); appears to have a bug as well and just hangs for every requset using the above code. I will continue to mess with things, because without knwoing when the 'load' even has fired - how will I properly take a screenshot if one page descides to load many things after domcontentloaded but before the load event. Basically I need to know when the load event has triggered, then I pause 2 more seconds and take a screenshot.

Comment: It's not a bug--it's just waiting for a load that's already occurred and won't occur again until a navigation is triggered, so it's a race condition. That's why I suggested removing it. This is the first time you've mentioned taking a screenshot. Please always provide full context because that can totally change the answer. In that case, networkidle may be a good bet, or waiting for all of the slowest elements to arrive, either via network responses or selectors. [Waiting is a poor solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73676564/6243352), usually a last resort.

Comment: To do what you just described, use `await page.goto(url); await page.waitForTimeout(2000); await page.screensht({path: "whatever.png"})`, keeping in mind that timeouts are unreliable race conditions.

Comment: See also my two answers in [Puppeteer wait until page is completely loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497252/puppeteer-wait-until-page-is-completely-loaded/72535642#72535642) which is applicable to screenshots, particularly if you're trying to take screenshots of arbitrary websites.

Comment: But then how do I access the page.on('domcontentloaded') if I am waiting for networkidle? If I add await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' }) the bug still exists.

Comment: I don't want to just await page.goto(url); await page.waitForTimeout(2000); Your answer was for me to wait for the 'domcontentloaded' to write javascript. If I only wait to that event, I am basically not able to track any of the other events and have to use a random pause? I tried this random pause and some pages don't load compeltely, and when things get ramped up the results are even buggier.

Comment: Please read the link I shared above for an explanation. `domcontentloaded` is a subset of the others, so if you wait for `networkidle` then the `domcontentloaded` and `load` events have already fired. If you use `page.goto(url)`, then `"load"` is the default value so you don't have to specify it. `"load"` can't fire until `"domcontentloaded"` already fires. If there's any doubt, you can pass an array argument to `waitUntil`, e.g. `page.goto(url, {waitUntil: ["load", "networkidle2"]})`, but I've never found a use case for this. `networkidle0` is most strict, often best for screenshots.

Comment: You don't need `page.on` here, almost certainly, nor `page.waitForNavigation`. I'm not sure which "bug" you're referring to, but if you wait for navigation without triggering one, you'll timeout because there's nothing to wait for `goto()` already resolves on navigation--that's the `{waitUntil: "..."}` arg. See [this post](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#making-unnecessary-calls-to-waitfornetworkidle-or-waitfornavigation) for further analysis of this common mistake.

Comment: Anyway, if you don't mind clearly stating your high-level requirements and provide websites you're working with, we can save a lot of time and guesswork and I can write an answer that directly solves your problem. Otherwise, we'll have a good deal of back and forth and probably not get too far.

Comment: "I tried this random pause and some pages don't load compeltely, and when things get ramped up the results are even buggier." yes, that's why I warned you and shared a link describing why you should never use timeouts. The reason I gave you that code was because you asked for "Basically I need to know when the load event has triggered, then I pause 2 more seconds and take a screenshot" and this code accomplishes exactly that. Providing the code is different from recommending actually using it.

Comment: It sounds like you want to screenshot arbitrary sites, no? If so, please read [the link above](It sounds like you want to screenshot arbitrary sites, no? If so, please read the link above about how that's going to be immensely difficult.) about how that's going to be immensely difficult.

Comment: The bug is on the  page.waitForNavigation. I should be adding that well before the event is firing, but it just times out... i've messed around with the link you provided and I believe I was able to get it working with return page.waitForNetworkIdle({idleTime: 100});  the waitForNetworkIdle is giving me the expected results (even thought it's not the load event - in theory it SHOULD be the same thing).

Comment: Also, Just wanted to say thank you so much for all of your comments and help! I have been messing with the same small bits of code for a while and your insight helped a lot.

Comment: Do not use `waitForNavigation` unless you're clicking on something that triggers a navigation. This is explained already. You can basically ignore that function for now, I doubt you'll need it. `waitForNetworkIdle` is also almost certainly not necessary. If you use `page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "networkidle0"})`, that implicitly waits 500 ms, making the extra network idle call meaningless. [This link already shared above](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#making-unnecessary-calls-to-waitfornetworkidle-or-waitfornavigation) explains this.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your purpose, it is possible to help better. you can also use the "page.&eval()" command if you want. You can use methods such as page.goto(), page.click(), page.type() to perform user actions. Example if you want to pull video;

```
const video = await page.evaluate((() => document.querySelector("video") ? document.querySelector("video").src : "");
```

Yes, with the code you wrote, you can process the fastest way after the dom is loaded. If you want to pull data you can use cheer.io.

Comment: I am taking screenshots of websites. If there is anything better to monitor for page loads, please let me know. Also, the website you suggest is dog treats.