# node js timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for the WS endpoint URL to appear in stdout

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, handlebars.js, html-to-pdf

I am using handlebars and puppeteer lib for generating pdfs . For handlebar input i am creating a array of data. Now i am looping through that data array and passing each record to puppeteer lib to generate pdf. I have large set of data . When loop is running entire application is hanging and it gives me the below error

How to loop data with puppeeteer so tht i can generate multiple pdf file base64 string

```
timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for the WS endpoint URL to appear in stdout! at ChromeLauncher.launch
```

below is the code

```
import { testres1 } from './getdata.js'
import { pdfrouter } from "./generatepdf.js";
import { insertdata } from "./insert.js";
import { pool } from "./dbconn.js";

        async function createPDF() {
            const insertquery = ('INSERT INTO base64staging(filename, base64str,testid) VALUES($1, $2, $3)');
            const queryPrommises1 = [];
            // const client = await pool.connect()
            const result = await testres1(pool) // This returns large set of data (10k to 20k records)
            console.log('result ' + result)
            var promiseresult = []
            if (result !== null && result !== undefined) {
                JSON.parse(result).forEach(async res => {
                    const res1 = await pdfrouter(res)
                    queryPrommises1.push(pool.query(insertquery, [res.employeeid.toString(), res1, res.testid]))
                    const result1 = await Promise.allSettled(queryPrommises1);
                    console.log(result1.length)
                     result1.forEach(res => {
                         if (res.status === 'fulfilled') {
                             promiseresult.push(res.value)
                         }
                    })
                })
                return promiseresult
            }
        }
    const testres2 = await createPDF()
```

pdf file creation function - generatepdf.js

```
const pdfrouter = async (data) => {
    process.setMaxListeners(Infinity)
    try {
        const templateHtml = fs.readFileSync(
            join(process.cwd(), "./index.html"),
            "utf8"
        );

        var template = Handlebars.compile(templateHtml);
        var html = encodeURIComponent(template(data));
        var milis = new Date();
        milis = milis.getTime();

        const options = {
            width: '1230px',
            headerTemplate: "<p></p>",
            footerTemplate: "<p></p>",
            displayHeaderFooter: false,
            margin: {
                top: "10px",
                bottom: "30px"
            },
            printBackground: true,
        };

        const browser = await launch({
            args: ['--no-sandbox'],
            headless: "new"
        });
        var page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log('Page opened')
        await page.goto(`data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,${html}`, {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
        });
        let pdfBuffer = await page.pdf(options);
        await browser.close();
        console.log("Done: invoice.pdf is created!");
        return pdfBuffer.toString('base64')

    } catch (err) {
        console.log("ERROR:", err);
        return err
    }

}

export { pdfrouter }
```

getdata.js - this js gets all the data needed for puppeteer

```
const testres1 = async (connection) => {
    console.log('entered create pdf')

    const query = `SELECT employeeid, uid, payout
    SUM(CAST(COALESCE(NULLIF(payout, ''), '0') AS decimal)) OVER(PARTITION BY employeeid) AS sumpayout
    FROM test_stage`
    const queryPrommises = [];
    queryPrommises.push(connection.query(query))
    //console.log(result.rows)
    const result = await Promise.all(queryPrommises);
    let tempmap = {}
    //console.log('result ' + result[0].rows[0])
    const res = Object.values(result[0].rows.reduce((all, y) => {
        const group = all[y.employeeid] || {
            employee_name: y.employeename,
            employee_id: y.employeeid,

            data: []
        };
        group.data.push({
            payout: y.payout
        })
        all[y.employeeid] = group;
        return all;
    }, {}));
    //await connection.end()

    //console.log('@@@@@ ' + JSON.stringify(res))

    return JSON.stringify(res)
}
```

Comment: What's `index.html` here? I don't see any loops or where `createPDF` is being called. Please share a complete, runnable [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: It is the html template created using handlebar node js lib, this template basically renders as pdf. " JSON.parse(result).forEach(async res => {" is loop in which i am calling "pdfRouter" function

Comment: Can you make some sample? I can't really help just by eyeballing the code. I need to run it and see the problem to be able to determine the best fix. package.json would be useful, too. Anyway, I see your loop now, although I'm not sure what's being parsed, `SON.parse(result).forEach(async res => {` looks wrong because [`.forEach` doesn't work with async code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop). This kicks off `n` browsers in parallel. `const result1 = await Promise.allSettled(queryPrommises1);` does not make it sequential.

Comment: [Crawling multiple URLs in a loop using Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293216/crawling-multiple-urls-in-a-loop-using-puppeteer/65000065#65000065) might help show a more standard pattern for looping with Puppeteer.

Comment: I have tried giving most of the info which i am trying to do . Please have a look .

Comment: Thanks--I don't have your db though, so I still can't run this code. I suggest further minimization so the question is more likely to be answered.

Comment: Any other suggestion .. how to loop puppeteer and handlebar for large data set ?

Comment: Sorry, not beyond what I've already mentioned. Did you try implementing the suggestions I offered? How did it go? I can't answer questions I can't run and validate, other than to say the code here won't work. The size of the data set shouldn't be terribly important, as long as you do it sequentially so you don't attempt to spawn hundreds or thousands of browsers at once, as the code here would do.