# How to dynamically create and chain fetch api calls?

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

In my application after the user submits a form, I have access to an array of images and I need to call our backend to save all of their uploaded photos to our cloud server.

Our /upload api endpoint takes one image at a time. How do I create an api call for each image in this array and chain them to happen one after another? I was thinking I could somehow use `reduce` to do this, but I'm not 100% sure how to go about it.

Here's how I'm making an api call for single image upload:

```
    const api = "https://appName.herokuapp.com/upload";
    const uri = photos[0];
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('image', {
      uri,
      name: `photo.jpg`,
      type: `image/jpg`,
    });

    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      headers: {
        Authorization:`Basic ${base64.encode(BACKEND_AUTHENTICATION_HEADER)}`,
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    };

    fetch(api, options)
      .catch((e) => console.log(e))
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24586168/2315280) should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Promise.All](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), you should be able to fire off multiple API calls and wait for all of them to resolve. 
The function passed to then() for a Promise.all receives an array containing the results.
For eg:

```
Promise.all([/*Array of promises*/]).then(function(results){
    //Results is an array
}).catch(function(error){
    //Handle errors
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsbin.com/yuqabizado/2/edit?html,js,output

Edit:
- Removed comment about compatibility issues with Promise.all. Thanks @zvona for pointing that out.

Comment: Correct answer: each `fetch` really needs to be handled as a promise in an array and executed with `Promise.all`. And as a sitenote: **RN Supports Promise.all natively, so no need to extend with bluebird**.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `redux` you could do something like:

- Create an array of images to be uploaded
- Create an action to upload the image which takes in index as a parameter and will recursively call itself for all following indexes
- When calling your action pass in index `0` and the action can recursively upload all images from that point

Logic behind this:

`imagesArray: [ image1, image2, image3 ]; // each image is an object`

Calling your action like:

```
store.dispatch(Actions.recursivelyUploadImages(0, imagesArray));
// If your action is defined outside of your current scope
// you can either bind it or pass in the imagesArray
```

Then your action would be defined something like:

```
recursivelyUploadImages(index, array) {
  // construct/define your api/options here
  fetch(api, options)
      .catch((e) => console.log(e))
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        if (index < array.length - 1) {
          // call recursiveUploadImages(index+1, array);
        }
      })
}
```

I don't now if this is a good solution, my knowledge of react and redux is very limited and I can only think about this kind of solution with my current experience.