# Way to store then fire sequential events in VueJS / Javascript (promises)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, event-handling, queue

What is the proper and best way to queue events on Javascript and then fire them one after another in right order (FIFO).

I've made something like that:

https://jsfiddle.net/zjsh0xq3/

My component is getting state from Vuex / Vue instance and it is synchronized according to DOM position (if those components will be resized from outside). For this example I made `List` component with position of items but the idea is the same.

So after I fired method on `ListItem` the parent component `List` is storing those events (data for operation) in array. And after that events are fired in right order one after another, but only if there is callback from `$emit` fired to say to `List` that this state of List has been changed in Vuex / Vue instance.

Does anyone have any better idea to solve this case or somewhere ready tool for queuing events?

I thought about promises like in this article: 
https://gist.github.com/anvk/5602ec398e4fdc521e2bf9940fd90f84

But I don't know how to prevent promises from being resolved until callback is called.

Thanks for advices!

Comment: duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110) i believe

Comment: There is no callback function inside those Promises and Promises are resolved one after another automatically. I need to have ability to prevent it from being called until I say so.