# Problems with Node.js and oracledb

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I'm having a problem with a node.js script at work (I'm pretty new to node in general, btw.). When I run through the forEach loop, it appears that it might be running asynchronously and therefor is not running problem. However, when I looked through the package documentation, I didn't see anything about get the sql execution to run synchronously. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
function getLastLoginAndProviderType(jsonObj, connection){
console.log(jsonObj);
jsonObj.forEach(obj => {
console.log("Processing: " + obj["email"]);
//obj["email"], obj["first"], obj["last"], obj["eid"], obj["role"] 

var sql = "select LAST_LOGGED_IN_TIME from EINV_OWNER.CONTACT where EMAIL_ADDRESS='" + obj['email'] + "'";

connection.execute(
  sql, {}, { maxRows: 15 },
  function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Query Error: " + err.message);
    } else {
      console.log("Number of rows returned: " + result.rows.length);

      obj["lastLoggedIn"] = "null";
      obj["supplierOrProvider"] = "null";
    }
  });
});
```

When the script runs, I would expect to see something like:

```
Processing: XXX@XXX.com
Number of rows returned: XX
Processing: XXX@XXX.com
Number of rows returned: XX
...
Processing: XXX@XXX.com
Number of rows returned: XX
```

However, what I end up getting is:

```
Processing: XXX@XXX.com
Processing: XXX@XXX.com
Processing: XXX@XXX.com
...
Processing: XXX@XXX.com
Query Error: NJS-003: invalid connection
Query Error: NJS-003: invalid connection
Query Error: NJS-003: invalid connection
...
Query Error: NJS-003: invalid connection
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick rundown on the basic options:

#### Callbacks

use package like https://github.com/caolan/async to easily manage a "for loop" of callbacks. (there are other packages)

`forEach` does not wait for your callback to complete, which is why they are all running at the same time. You can also manage your own for-loop by using a callback with an iterator that stops when the max iterator is reached.

But you could also use :

`require('util').promisify` to convert a node.js styled callback function

```
myFn(foo,bar,<function(err,data){}>)
```

to a promise which then you can do the following:

#### Promises

[Resolve promises one after another (i.e. in sequence)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence)

#### Async/Await

Or what you probably would want...

```
async function myFunction(){
  for(i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++){
    try{
      let result = await connection.execute(sql, {}, { maxRows: 15 })
      console.log("Number of rows returned: " + result.rows.length);
      obj["lastLoggedIn"] = "null";
      obj["supplierOrProvider"] = "null";
    }catch(e){
      console.error("Query Error: " + err.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the quick response! I have one followup question, in your final example of Async/Await, how do I then use my callback function that I currently have in my execute call?

Comment: I'm also getting an error after doing "npm install utils" where it says "TypeError: require(...).promisify is not a function" thanks a ton!!!!

Comment: Sorry it is `require('util')` not `utils`

Comment: Actually it looks like oracledb supports it out of the box

Comment: Thank, mate. You are amazing!

Comment: @jhammond since the answer resolved your issue, kindly *accept* it (answers take up valuable time for respondents).