# Wait The past function to finish to start a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have 4 Ajax functions the first is independent , 
but all the other three functions are dependent on the ones before . 
Real example : 
I Have Country , Governorate , District , Town and Road
the Country can be called directly 
while all the others have to wait till the ones before 
I made sure that all functions are working right and they get data ,
"so there is no problem with ajax request ". 
after I have tried those two methods :

```
$.when(GetCountry()).then(function(){
    GetGovernerate();
}).then(function(){
    GetDistrict(GovernerateID);
}).then(GetTown(DistrictID)).then(function(){
    GetRoad(TownID)
});
```

I have also tried the **done** method  :

```
$.when(GetCountry()).done(function(){
    GetGovernerate();
}).done(function(){
    GetDistrict(GovernerateID);
}).done(GetTown(DistrictID)).done(function(){
    GetRoad(TownID)
});
```

The result is that both of them get the governerate elements and all the rest are not called (resolved).
i have looked to the console for any error, 
but nothing to show .

I did a work around example for it but this is not as productive as call back functions :

```
setTimeOut(function(){
    GetGovernerate()
},150,function(){
    setTimeOut(function(){
        GetDistrict();
    },150,function(){
        GetTown();
    });
});
```

I have looked into the explanation of jquery , but am not understanding it .
Can any one please make it easier to me to understand .

Comment: You need to return the promise in the `then()` functions if you want the next `then` to wait: `.then(function(){ return GetDistrict(GovernerateID)})` (assuming these functions return promises).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve promises one after another (i.e. in sequence)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3874623/mark-meyer it work only for the district ,  but the town and road are not working .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630817/just-code I truly did not understand the idea , does this mean , that  in each function i have to do a (var promise = $.Deferred(); /*statement of function*/ then i do a return promise.Promise() ?  )

Comment: You just need to return the promise, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31070150/542251)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working code for you. I had to add `sleep` to simulate ajax delays.

Your problem is you are not returning promises of function calls.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ergec/gbpd8zy2/)

```
//Chain one after another using previous object
$.when(GetCountry()).then(function() {
  return GetGovernerate();
}).then(function() {
  return GetDistrict();
}).then(function() {
  return GetTown();
}).then(function() {
  return GetRoad();
}).done(function() {
  $("body").append("<p>all done</p>");
});

//all needed functions
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function GetCountry() {
  $("body").append("GetCountry<br>");
  return sleep(1000);
}

function GetGovernerate() {
  $("body").append("GetGovernerate<br>");
  return sleep(1000);
}

function GetDistrict() {
  $("body").append("GetDistrict<br>");
  return sleep(1000);
}

function GetTown() {
  $("body").append("GetTown<br>");
  return sleep(1000);
}

function GetRoad() {
  $("body").append("GetRoad<br>");
  return sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: This answer needs an explanation of what you changed and why

Comment: @Liam Edited my answer, I think is better now. Since there are several ways to do this I did my way but now edited it to match his code.

Comment: I really think the words (to the effect of), "you need to return the promise in your then" need to be in here, that's the nub of the problem here