# How to properly Loop through SMS sending via Twilio Functions

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

I have Twilio Studio calling a Twilio Function and need it to send email to a variable list (small list) of emails. This question is mostly around looping through them as I can pass variables just fine. I have an array of emails to send a text to and am in a Twilio Function. But all examples I find online are about sending to just ONE. Part of me thinks this needs to be a Twilio Function calling another Twilio function (one loops, the other sends Emails)... but I can't figure out a way to do that. If I could contain it to one Twilio function, that would be great.

I have Twilio Studio calling a Twilio function. I need to keep this all on Twilio... so looping through via PHP and running functions one at a time through there doesn't work. I need this to run on Twilio's serverless setup.

Here's an example of what I have that works:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    // using SendGrid's v3 Node.js Library
    // https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs
    const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
    sgMail.setApiKey(context.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
    const msg = {
      to: 'me@example.com',
      from: 'noreply@example.com',
      templateId: 'my-id-goes-here',
      dynamic_template_data: {
        recipient_name: 'John Smith'
      }
    };
    sgMail.send(msg).then(response => {
      let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
      callback(null, twiml);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      callback(err);
    });
};
```

Here's me trying to loop through in similar fashion and failing

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

    sgMail.setApiKey(context.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

    var responder_emails = 'me@example.com,me+test1@example.com';
    var emails_a = responder_emails.split(',');

    emails_a.forEach(function(responder_email) {
        const msg = {
          to: responder_email,
          from: 'noreply@example.com',
          templateId: 'my-id-goes-here',
          dynamic_template_data: {
            recipient_name: 'John Smith'
          }
        };
        sgMail.send(msg);
    });

    callback();
};
```

I can pass in multiple emails into a Twilio function... I'm just not sure how to loop through correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heyo. Twilio Evangelist here.

In your first example, you rightfully waited for the `send` call to be done by using `then`. In your second example, you missed that. You run several `send` calls but immediately call `callback` without waiting.

A fixed (roughly prototyped version) could look as follows.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

  sgMail.setApiKey(context.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

  var responder_emails = 'me@example.com,me+test1@example.com';
  var emails_a = responder_emails.split(',');

  Promise.all(emails_a.map(function(responder_email) {
    const msg = {
      to: responder_email,
      from: 'noreply@example.com',
      templateId: 'my-id-goes-here',
      dynamic_template_data: {
        recipient_name: 'John Smith'
      }
    };
    return sgMail.send(msg);
  })).then(function() {
    callback();
  }).catch(function(e) {
    callback(e);
  })
});
```

You have already an array of emails because you called `split`. You can use this array in combination with `Array.map` and `Promise.all`.

Map basically iterates over your array and lets you create a new array with whatever you return from the function inside of map. What the code above does is that it transforms `[email, email]` to `[Promise, Promise]`. The promises are the return value of `sgMail.send`.

Now, that you have an array holding promises that will resolve when sendgrid accepted your call, you can use `Promise.all`. This method waits for all the promises to be resolved (or rejected) and returns itself a new promise which you can use `then` with. When all sendgrid calls are done it's time to finish the function by calling the function `callback`.

Side note: this "map/Promise.all" trick performs all send grid calls in parallel. There might be situations where you want to call them [one after another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence) (saying you are doing a lot of calls and run into rate limiting).

Hope that helps and let me know how it goes. :)

Comment: My coworkers just saw me to a happy dance. Using Promise was the missing piece for me. I do understand what you mean by rate limiting, we're already planning for increases in those with Twilio. But in this function, it's fairly contained to a handful each time it's called. Thank you!

Comment: Happy I could help. 