# How to create a loop with instead of .then call

Tags: node.js

I want to insert infos from JIRA to a Sql Server,
The JIRA server restrict me on the number of request I send in parallel so I have to dilute the number of call I can send in the same time.

I did it this way first and it works :

```
    mainJira.getAllPendingIssue(totalIssues).then(function(issues){
      var pendingTicket = mainJira.pop_to_array(issues)

      JiraToSql(pendingTicket,0,100)
      .then(
        JiraToSql(pendingTicket,100,200))
      .then(
        JiraToSql(pendingTicket,200,300))
    })
```

But as the number of issues may vary, I would like to do it in a loop.
I tried this way but it doesn't work

```
      mainJira.getAllPendingIssue(totalIssues).then(function(issues){
        var pendingTicket = mainJira.pop_to_array(issues)
        for (pas = 0; pas < totalIssues; pas+= 50 ){
          console.log('pas : ',pas );        
          JiraToSql(pendingTicket,pas,pas + 50);
          } 
        })    
      })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve promises one after another (i.e. in sequence)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence)

Answer (score 0):

use `array.forEach()` on the result of your `getAllPendingIssue()` function call

```
mainJira.getAllPendingIssue(totalIssues).then(function(issues){
      var pendingTicket = mainJira.pop_to_array(issues);
      pendingTicket.forEach(function(issue){
           modifiedJiraToSQL(issue); 
      });
```

**Note:** about the `modifiedJiraToSQL()` function, you need to base this on your `JiraToSQL()` function to handle only one issue at a time.