# Chain of promises in javascript with ajax calls

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function (f1) which I want to get called only after two ajax calls (say a1 and a2) are done. a2 should be called only after a1 is done. Following is the sequence of operation =

```
$.when(a1 and a2) {
   f1
}
```

I tried the following code snippet -

```
$.when(a1a2()).done(function(){
  f1();
}

var a1a2 = function(){
  return $.when(a1()).done(function() {
    if (<check for a few variables a1 sets>) {
      // another ajax call for which f1 should wait
      return a2();
    } else {
      // random function for which f1 shouldn't wait
      f2();
    }
  });
}
```

In the above code, f1 is waiting for a1 to finish but it is not waiting for a2 to finish.

I tried the following code snippet as well (but this also just waits for a1 to finish) -

```
var a1a2 = function(){
  var retVal = new Promise(function(){
    a1().then(function(){
      if (<check for a few variables a1 sets>) {
        return a2();
      } else {
        // random function for which f1 shouldn't wait
        f2();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I have looked at other similar questions but an not able to devise a solution. Can someone please help?

Comment: `new Promise(function(){` that's NOT how you create a Promise - that promise will remain pending forever

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve promises one after another (i.e. in sequence)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your Promise code is faulty, because you're not creating a Promise correctly

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // in here you call resolve or reject otherwise Promise is forever pending
});
```

However, since `a1` returns a Promise (as do all the functions, I'm assuming) you don't need to create a promise

So, your code would be

```
a1()
.then(function() {
    if (somecondition == true) {
        return a2();
    } else {
        f2(); // since there's no return here, there's no "wait" for the promise f2 returns
    }
})
.then(function() {
    return f1();
})
```

To illustrate the above, here's your code once with condition true, and then with condition false

Take note of the "time stamps" for the console output

```js
// dummy code to set up some promises
const dummy = (x, d=1000) => {
    console.log(performance.now(), 'start', x);
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(performance.now(), 'end', x);
        resolve(x);
    }, d));
};

const a1 = () => dummy('a1');
const a2 = () => dummy('a2');
const f1 = () => dummy('f1');
const f2 = () => dummy('f2', 3000);

// end dummy code

console.log('wait for a2');
a1()
.then(function() {
    if (true) {
        return a2();
    } else {
        // random function for which f1 shouldn't wait
        f2();
    }
})
.then(function() {
    return f1();
})
.then(() => {
    console.log('dont wait for f2');
    a1()
    .then(function() {
        if (false) {
            return a2();
        } else {
            // random function for which f1 shouldn't wait
            f2();
        }
    })
    .then(function() {
        f1();
    });
});
```

> However! If f2 is a function that has no asynchrony then there is no way **<sup>*</sup>** to prevent f1 from being called after f2 finish - because that's how javascript works
>
> **<sup>*</sup>** - I guess you could put it in a setTimeout, then f2 would execute after f1 begins (again, assuming f1 has some asynchrony, otherwise f2 would begin after f1 ends)

Answer (score 2):

Call `a1` to get its Promise, then call `Promise.all` on `a1` and `a1` chained with `a2`:

```
const a1Prom = a1();
Promise.all([
  a1Prom,
  a1Prom.then(a2)
])
  .then(f1);
```

```js
console.log('script start');

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
const a1 = () => delay(1000).then(() => console.log('a1 done'));
const a2 = () => {
  console.log('a2 starting');
  return delay(1000).then(() => console.log('a2 done'));
};

const f1 = () => console.log('f1 starting');



const a1Prom = a1();
Promise.all([
  a1Prom,
  a1Prom.then(a2)
])
  .then(f1);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, it isn't waiting for a2's execution. a2 is not returning any promise

Comment: Yeah, you need to make sure `a2` returns a Promise in order to use it with asynchronous code like this (but you didn't post any of the `a2` code). If you do that, press "Run code snippet", you'll see that it runs as desired

Comment: Is there any way I can either return a promise or null (in case I don't want to wait)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the when/done syntax, but this is a correction for your second snippet. A big hint I would give is that using `new Promise` is 90% of the time a bad idea.

```
var a1a2 = function(){
  var retVal = a1().then(function(){
    if (<check for a few variables a1 sets>) {
      return a2();
    } else {
      // random function for which f1 shouldn't wait
      f2();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function a1() {
  return new Promise(resolve => { 
     resolve();
  });
}

function a2() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve();
  });
}

function f1() {
  // this runs when the a1 and a2 is resolved.
}

// this is the call method. there are so many approach in your question first is chaining of promise.
function CallMethod(){
   a1().then(function () { // you can optionally pass data here via the resolve in the promise
      return a2();
   }).then(function () { // same here you can pass optional data here.
      // here the a1 and a2 is resolved you can call the f1() now.
      f1();
   });
}
// second one is called Promise.all()
function CallMethod() {
  Promise.all([a1(), a2()]).then(data => { // this is the optional data passed in the resolve base on the index of the function promises. 
     var firstResolve = data[0]; // resolved data of a1();
     var secondResolve = data[1]; // resolved data of a2();
  })
}
```