# Call multiple registers in Realtime from Firebase Cloud 'at same time'

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send some pushes to users when a 'invitation' is written in Realtime DB.

When the cloud function detects the creation of the invitation is triggered, and recovers the users list to ve invited (id's).

Once I get this id's I have to recover the user info for each id, in order to get some info like language, fcmTokens, etc..

Reading some SO questions I saw that I have to create a reference to the "call" like:

```
admin.database().ref(`/user/${userId}`).once('value')
```

Then store it in an array and call with Promise.all()

```
var userPromises = [];
for (var i = 0;i<usersInRange.length; i++) {
     var userId = usersInRange[i];
     userPromises[i] = admin.database().ref(`/user/${userId}`).once('value');
}
Promise.all(userPromises).then(results => {
...
})
```

And here is where I need help.

I'm having some problems , because if Promise.all() fails in retrieving some user, it stops, and don't read the other id's.

There is a way to do it "one by one" to avoid Promise.all() stop?

Comment: Which action do you want to do on the documents you read? Modify them? Which kind of error you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence) you can find a similar question which is already answered. Summarizing, they say that you can use an async function (if possible). Another approach is to use a loop.

```
function runSerial(tasks) {
    var result = Promise.resolve();
    tasks.forEach(task => {
      result = result.then(() => task());
    });
    return result;
}
```

It worth to take a look into it.