# How to change Promise.all to send requests one by one

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, lodash

I have a an array of chunked data that I need to upload one chunk at time. The current implementation I used it to encapsulate the logic in an Promise.all() since I need to return the result of the promise,
The problem with this approach is that all the upload is done asynchronously resulting in a Timeout error as the server can't process all the requests at the same time, How can I modify this method so that the upload is done one chunk at time ?.

My code:

```
var chunks = _.chunk(variableRecords, 30);
return Promise.all(
        chunks.map(chunk => this.portalService.updateDataForChart(variableId, chunk)))
        .then((updateRes: boolean[]) => {
          if (updateRes.every(updateStatus => updateStatus)) {
            return this.executeRequest<HealthDataSource, boolean>({
              path: `/variable/user/datasources/${dataSource.identifier}`,
              method: 'PUT',
              body: {
                libelle: dataSource.datasource.libelle,
                type: dataSource.datasource.type,
                lastSyncDate: Math.max(maxDate, dataSource.datasource.lastSyncDate)
              },
              headers: this.getHeaders()
            });
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve promises one after another (i.e. in sequence)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need them in **SEQUENCE** , for of is the way to go :

```
async function chunksSequence(chunks) {
  for(const chunk of chunks) {
    await // your other code here
  }
};
```

*If you need to return something*

```
async function chunksSequence(chunks) {
  let results = []
  for(const chunk of chunks) {
    let result = await // your other code here
    results.push(result)
  }
  return results 
};
```

**Because of comment needed in a promise on return**

```
async function chunksSequence(chunks) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    let results = []
    for(const chunk of chunks) {
      let result = await // your other code here
      results.push(result)
    }
    resolve(results) 
  }
};
```

Comment: How do you get all the results at the end ?

Comment: @Weedoze, simply add a collector array before the loop, push every result to it and return that at the end of the function.

Comment: @CerebralFart Indeed, it would be better to add this part to the code as OP needs to handle the final results

Comment: done eddited,  with the return part, give feedback if needed :)

Comment: the return type should be a Promise as I'm going to use a .then on it to execute the PUT request

Comment: done added your case too :) check the eddited answer, feel free to have it as the accepted answer hehehe

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the help of `Array.reduce()`

```
const chunks = _.chunk(variableRecords, 30);
return tasks.reduce((promiseChain, currentTask) => {
    return promiseChain.then(chainResults =>
        currentTask.then(currentResult =>
            [ ...chainResults, currentResult ]
        )
    );
}, Promise.resolve([])).then(arrayOfResults => {
    // Do something with all results
});
```

Source : https://decembersoft.com/posts/promises-in-serial-with-array-reduce/

Comment: This assumes that `variableRecords` is an array of promises, wherein the process of requesting from the server has already been established. It will still have the same problem as the OP, as the server can't process all requests at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't / can't use `await` you could use something like this

```
function runSequenceItem(chunks, index) {
 return new Promise(chunks[index])
  .then(res => {
     index ++
     if (index < chunks.length) {
       return runSequence(chunks[index], index + 1)
     } else {
       // this is not needed actually
       return 'done'
     }
   })
}

function runInSequence(chunks) {
 return runSequenceItem(chunks, 0)
}
```

If you also need the results then you can return an array at the end of the recursion `runInSequence`

```
    function runSequenceItem(chunks, index, results) {
 return new Promise(chunks[index])
  .then(res => {
     results.push(res)
     index ++
     if (index < chunks.length) {
       return runSequence(chunks[index], index + 1)
     } else {
       return results
     }
   })
}

function runInSequence(chunks) {
 return runSequenceItem(chunks, 0, [])
}
```

and then retrieve it at the end

```
let results = runInSequence(chunks)
```