# Javascript labels continue statement won't work in functions inside while loops

Tags: javascript

So, when i use a continue statement in a function inside a while loop, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Undefined label 'start'
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

Here is my code:

```js
var continuable = true;
start: while(true){
    console.log('Executed the code!');
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (continuable == true){
            continue start;
        }
    }, 250);
    break;
```

Comment: Your continue statement is *in another function*. By the time it executes, the current function that has the label has finished executing and the stack has been long cleared of it. How would a jump back even work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only break or continue a loop using `break` or `continue` if the loop is inside the function you're currently in. In this case, your `continue start` is referencing a loop which is *outside* of the current running function, so it's not permitted.

You can make it work by `await`ing 250ms inside a loop instead:

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

(async () => {
  var continuable = true;
  setTimeout(() => { continuable = false; }, 1500);
  start: while(true){
    console.log('Executed the code!');
    await delay(250);
    if (continuable == true){
      console.log('continuing');
      continue start;
    }
    console.log('not continuing, executing body of loop');
  }
})();
```

Comment: Surprising we can await inside a while

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not sure it's very surprising. [You can do it in a `for..of`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence), so I can't see a reason why it can't be in any loop constructs. Since `await` puts the function to sleep, there is no real inherent problem with this, when the Promise is resolved, the function context is restored and execution resumes anyway.

Comment: You can also do it in normal `for` loops, as well as (weird) bare blocks

Comment: I am just so used to the computer not getting any time to update inside such a loop