# How to create a loop that can be programatically iterated when inner callback is executed?

Tags: javascript

I am iterating over an array of assets, I need to load each of these assets to gpu (using third party library for this). Loader provided by such third party library has a callback function that is executed when asset is loaded i.e. right now I have something like this

```js
assetsArr.forEach(asset => {
   myLoader.upload(asset, () => {
      // Go to next loop / iteration here
   })
});
```

Since this callback is not executed right away I am currently in a situation where my loop finishes before my assets are actually loaded leading to some issues in my app.

Is there a way to loop over `assetsArr`, but only go to next iteration / loop once that callback is executed?

Comment: A [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) might be good here, where the .next() function does the upload and returns true when there are assets left to upload.

Comment: @Gavin this is not what generators are for.

Comment: Does this `upload()` function use Promises?

Comment: Or [promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24586168/2244284).

Comment: @RoboRobok unfortunately no

Comment: How are you informed that the file finished uploading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by wrapping `myLoader` in a `Promise`. As I dont have the code for `myLoader` I'll simulate it with a delay which just waits a few seconds.

```js
async function dummyUpload(asset){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
         console.log("dummyUpload",asset);
         setTimeout(resolve,3000);
    });
}

async function test(assets){
    for(var i=0;i<assets.length;i++){
        var asset = assets[i];
        console.log("starting",asset);
        await dummyUpload(asset);
        console.log("finished",asset);
    };
}
var assets = [1,2,3];
test(assets);
```

The way to wrap your upload function is fairly simple:

```
async function loaderFunction(asset){
    return new Promise( resolve => {
        myLoader.upload(asset, resolve);
    });
}
```

You may also want to check if your "loader" supports a Promise-based interface which would be better than wrapping in another `Promise`.

Comment: I love wrapping things in Promises and using `async`/`await` approach. It doesn't get any cleaner that this. Synchronous code style is the most convenient one, always.

Comment: @RoboRobok Yes just note my last line, so you dont fall into the [promise-wrapping anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: That was an interesting read, thanks. Always keen on learning another anti-pattern :D

Answer (score 0):

Create function `loader` like below and call it with `loader(assetsArr, 0);`. Inside `callback` function at the end add code `index++;` and check `if (index < assetsArr.length)` then `loader(assetsArr, index);`.

Test it below. For testing I have added custom code for `myLoader`.

```js
let myLoader = {
  upload : (asset, callback) => setTimeout(callback, 1000)
};

let assetsArr = [1, 2, 3];

function loader(assetsArr, index) {
  let asset = assetsArr[index];
  myLoader.upload(asset, () => {
    console.log(index);
    // Go to next loop / iteration here      
    index++;
    if (index < assetsArr.length) {
      loader(assetsArr, index);
    }
  })
}

loader(assetsArr, 0);
```

Comment: If OP needs to perform some other task after all the assets are uploaded, you may need to either accept a callback from the `loader` function or `loader` function should return a promise. Once the last asset is loaded (`else` branch of your `if`), that callback should be invoked or the promise should be resolved.