# How to sequence the .then() calls in a specific order?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I am fairly new to the concept of promises, I am trying to build a simple pokemon list (aka pokedex). I am using the following code.

I want the names of the pokemons to be listed according to their indicies, I don't want the order to get disturbed. The code that I am using currently using doesn't guarantee this feature.

Inside the `forEach()` method the `fetch()` calls are not chained in any manner, so it depends on which response is received first, but I want the `then()` of index `x` to be executed before `then()` of index `x+1`.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=150')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    json.results.forEach((el, index) => {
      fetch(el.url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          const pokemonName = el.name;
          const pokemontype = json.types[0].type.name;
          container.innerHTML += `(${index+1}) ${pokemonName} - ${pokemontype} <br>`;
        })
    })
  })
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

> UPDATE: Below is my solution for the same using `Promise.all()`

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=150')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    const responseArr = [];
    json.results.forEach(el => {
      responseArr.push(fetch(el.url));
    });

    return Promise.all(responseArr);
  })
  .then(responses => {
    const jsonArr = [];
    responses.forEach(el => {
      jsonArr.push(el.json());
    });

    return Promise.all(jsonArr);
  })
  .then(jsons => {
    jsons.forEach((json, index) => {
      const pokemonName = json.name;
      const pokemonType = json.types[0].type.name;
      container.innerHTML += `(${index+1}) ${pokemonName} - ${pokemonType} <br>`;
    });
  })
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Put the promises in an array, then use `Promise.all()` to process the results in the order of the array.

Comment: Use `Promise.all()` or `async/await`

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Promise.all` and pass the result from the first API call, this will return the responses in the order as requested:

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=150')
  .then(response => response.json(), e => {
    console.error(e);
    throw e;
  })
  .then(json => {
    Promise.all(json.results.map(el => fetch(el.url)))
      .then(arr => {
        arr.map(response => response.json())
          .forEach((result, index) => {
            result.then(el => {
              const pokemonName = el.name;
              const pokemontype = el.types[0].type.name;
              container.innerHTML += `(${index+1}) ${pokemonName} - ${pokemontype} <br>`;
            })
          })
      }).catch(e => {
        console.error(e)
        throw e;
      });
  }).catch(e => {
    console.error(e)
    throw e;
  });
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: I think your solution is NOT completely correct, because you're using Promise.all() only ONCE. You've assumed that response.json() will follow the order and json promises will be returned in order. Please have a look at my updated question I have pasted my solution there. There I have used Promise.all() twice. Am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: `arr.map(response => response.json()).forEach((result, index) => {result.then(.........`
Here result.then() may not follow the order, the first once to get fulfilled will be printed first.

Comment: Your Code doesn't work try changing the api endpoint to `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=15` and see how the order gets messed up.