# Angular Async not apearing in order

Tags: angular, typescript

I am testing Async await in my angular application.

Here is the code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  
  async main() {
    await this.one();
    await this.two();
    await this.three();
  }

  async one() {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      console.log('one finished');
    }, 5000);
  }

  async two() {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      console.log('two finished');
    }, 1000);
  }

  async three() {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      console.log('three finished');
    }, 4000);
  }

}
```

When I look into the console it's not appearing as intended.

It's appearing in order: two, three and one.

I need it to appear in order one, two and finally three.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your one, two and three don't await their respective timeout but return immediately. You must return a promise that resolves in the callback of the timeout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to control setTimeout with promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64138772/how-to-control-settimeout-with-promises)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Angular, this is how JavaScript works.

See this vanilla JS version:

```js
class AppComponent  {
  async main() {
    await this.one();
    await this.two();
    await this.three();
  }

  async one() {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      console.log('one finished');
    }, 5000);
  }

  async two() {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      console.log('two finished');
    }, 1000);
  }

  async three() {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      console.log('three finished');
    }, 4000);
  }
}

let x = new AppComponent();
x.main();
```

I think you are expecting `one()` to take 5000 seconds, `two()` to take 1000 seconds and `three()` to take 4000 seconds to execute.

But Actually, they execute instantaneously, it set a timeOut and return the control flow to the caller.

Since `console.log`s are inside the timeOut functions, based on the timeout intervals.

You can create a `setTimout` function and await it on `one()`, `two()` and `three()`

```js
async function setTimeouAsync(fn, ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    }).then(() => {
        fn();
    });
}


@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;

  async main() {
    await this.one();
    await this.two();
    await this.three();
  }

  async one() {
    await setTimeouAsync(() => {
      console.log("one finished");
    }, 5000);
  }

  async two() {
    await setTimeouAsync(() => {
      console.log("two finished");
    }, 1000);
  }

  async three() {
    await setTimeouAsync(() => {
      console.log("three finished");
    }, 4000);
  }

  constructor() {
    this.main();
  }
}
```

An example can be found [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-64579655?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` does not return a `Promise` which you can await. You would need to do the following to make it work:

```
timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async doSomething() {
  await timeout(5000);
  await timeout(1000);
  await timeout(3000);
}
```