# axios - node.js - how to add delays with dynamic requests with await/async

Tags: javascript, axios

I am expanding my pet project (twitterwatcher.com/c/) with alerts, for that, I need to get a bit more details from the binance API, long story short I am receiving an error:
509, Bandwidth Limit Exceeded

I guess that I am sending the requests to the binance in a way to rapid manner - and I have to introduce a form of delay into my axios requests.
And now here comes the problem - as my code is doing it automatically - how can I add the delays?

below the JS code:

```
let urls = ['A', 'B', 'C'] //this id dynamic 
let output = null; 
const responses = await axios.all(urls.map(x => axios.get(x)));
if(Array.isArray(responses)){
        output = []; 
        responses.forEach(wip => {wip.data.forEach((element) => {
            output.push({
                //push the JSON in
            });
        });
    })
}else{
    output = []; 
    outputWiP.data.forEach((element) => {
            output.push({
                //push the JSON in
            });
        });
    })
}
```

And a question:

- How can I introduce a 0.5s delay without major changes in the logic?
  I've seen solutions with .then() approach, I do not want to have a unique implementation in this piece of code (I am using async/await wherever I can).

Comment: Replace your promise.all with a for of.  You can then also add a simple promise delay with await.

Comment: @Keith will try, thank you. I was hoping for an extra "hidden" param in the get configuration that can enforce the delay. I guess this is not that common case for it to be there.

Comment: note for self - check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence/41115086#41115086

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this approach. Works.

```
/*
 * serial executes Promises sequentially.
 * @param {funcs} An array of funcs that return promises.
 * @example
 * const urls = ['/url1', '/url2', '/url3']
 * serial(urls.map(url => () => $.ajax(url)))
 *     .then(console.info.bind(console)) 
 */
const serial = funcs =>
    funcs.reduce((promise, func) =>
        promise.then(
            result => func().then(Array.prototype.concat.bind(result))), 
            Promise.resolve([]))
```

solution from [Resolve promises one after another (i.e. in sequence)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence/41115086#41115086)

IMPORTANT: It is not with a delay, BUT sequentional.

Answer (score 1):

This should work i guess

```
urls.map(x => {
     setTimeout(() => {
        axios.get(x);    
     }, 500);
});
```

Comment: You do know that this will just delay all urls for half a second?  IOW: all requests are still going to happen at the same time, just half a second later..