# Trouble with resolving promises in sequence

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to resolve an array of promises in the build process of a NextJS app since I'm getting network errors when using Promise.all, but for some reason I'm having trouble resolving the promises.

This code works, but does not work with my build:

```
const activityPlacesPromises = activityLocationIDs.map((id) =>
    this.get(`places/${id}`)
);

const activityPlaces = await Promise.all(activityPlacesPromises);

console.log(activityPlaces); // Returns the data correctly
```

This code does not work:

```
const activityPlaces = activityLocationIDs.reduce((promise, id) => {
    return promise.then(() => this.get(`places/${id}`));
}, Promise.resolve());

console.log(activityPlaces); // Returns Promise { <pending> }
```

Why isn't the Promise.resolve() reduce function working?

PS: I am going off of this SO question: [Resolve promises one after another (i.e. in sequence)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequenceja)

Comment: just `const result = await activityPlaces`. Because at that point it's just a chain of `promise.then` so it's still a promise, not a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activityPlace` is still just a promise you will need to await

```js
console.log(await activityPlaces);
```

Note that you're not doing anything with the result of each promise (aside from the last one)

Wouldn't it be way easier to just throw this in a regular for loop and await one by one? the reduce pattern is useful for cases where you don't have async/await, but you don't seem to have this limitation:

```js
const results = [];

for(const id of activityLocationIDs) {
  results.push(await this.get(`places/${id}`));
}

console.log(result);
```

The above code matches the behavior of your first sample.

Comment: Ah, okay I didn't realize the reduce pattern was for environments where you couldn't use async/await. Your example works nicely, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to avoid using `async/await`, firstly perhaps you should catch any errors, to allow logging and execution to continue:

```js
const activityPlaces = activityLocationIDs.reduce((promise, id) => {
    return promise
        .then(() => this.get(`places/${id}`))
        .catch((err) => console.error(`Error getting place ID: ${id}`, err))
}, Promise.resolve());

activityPlaces.then(() => console.log(activityPlaces));
```

Also, consider that since your code is no longer using async, your build may not wait for the promises to resolve before ending.