# run multiple fetch calls in order

Tags: javascript, fetch, fetch-api

I have an array of sizes that I am looping through in order to run a fetch api call with the size as a parameter of the url. The issue I am having is that I would like run the api calls in order and push the response up to a bigger array so that all the data is collated together. I cant seem to push this response data up to the array in the order of the original size array. My code currently looks like this:

```js
sizeOptionsArr.forEach((option, index) => {
  const storeAPI = `https://api-url/json/store-stock-lookup?productCode=${option}`
  return fetch(storeAPI)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      fullDataArr.push(data.data)
      console.log(index)
    })
})
```

When I console log the index this appears in a random sequence every time which suggests that the api calls are all running in sync or in a random order.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence

Comment: What you actually want to use is `Promise.all`, which collects the results in the expected order. And still allows the requests to run concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `Promise.all` to run the API requests in parallel and still get the responses in order.

```js
const promises = sizeOptionsArr.map((option) => {
  const storeAPI = `https://api-url/json/store-stock-lookup?productCode=${option}`
  return fetch(storeAPI)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => data.data)
});

Promise.all(promises)
  .then((responses) => {
    fullDataArr.push(...responses)
  });
```