# Promise running simultaneously rather than sequentially

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, async-await, promise

I have different functions running in different if statements. I want to go back to the previous `else if` after the one of the other has been run. I tried to write a promise but that ran too soon.

My code:

```
(async() => {
  let dev = await getAllTables({
    query: tables(dev_id)
  });
  let prod = await getAllTables({
    query: tables(prod_org)
  });

  result.data.table_fields.forEach((d) => {
    if (d.type != "connected_field") {
      axiosfunc1();
    } else if (d.label in dev) {
      axiosfunc2();
    } else if (d.label in prod) {
      axiosfunc3()
      .then((res) => res)
      .then((x) => {
         axiosfunc2();
       });
    } else {
      console.log(`${d.label} DOES NOT EXIST}`);
    }
  });
})();
```

`axiosfunc2()` is running at the same time as `axiosfunc3()` rather than having `axiosfunc3()` run first and then `axiosfunc2()`.

How do I fix that?

Comment: I doubt `d.label in prod` is executing both at the same. It is more likely that `table_fields` contains labels that are both in `dev` and `prod` so different iterations are kicking off different branches of the `if` statement concurrently

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolve promises one after another (i.e. in sequence)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `for...of` loop and `await` all the `Promise`s so that they are executed sequentially.

```js
for (const d of result.data.table_fields) {
    if (d.type != "connected_field") {
      await axiosfunc1();
    } else if (d.label in dev) {
      await axiosfunc2();
    } else if (d.label in prod) {
      const res = await axiosfunc3();
      await axiosfunc2();
    } else {
      console.log(`${d.label} DOES NOT EXIST}`);
    }
}
```