# Q promises chaining to do things in correct order

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have a asynchronous function that needs to be called multiple times in the correct order. It's about uploading images to a server but like I said the images should be uploaded in the correct order.

My function looks like this:

```
  function uploadImage(sku,fileName) {
    console.log("Uploading image for sku="+sku+", imageName="+fileName);

    var deferred = Q.defer();

    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(rootPath+'/data/'+sku+"/"+fileName);
    var req = request.post('http://localhost:3000/'+sku+'/upload/'+fileName);

    readStream.pipe(req);

    req.on('end', function() {
      console.log("Image imageName="+fileName+" uploaded successfully.");
      db.updateLastUploadedImage(sku,fileName).then(function (res) {
        if(res) {
          console.log("Table watches for sku="+sku+" updated.");
          deferred.resolve(sku);
        }
      });
    });

    req.on('error',function(err) {
      deferred.reject(err);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

I tried to bring it on with chaining the promises like documented in https://github.com/kriskowal/q but it's not working well. Somehow I do not come to the "then" block.

So I tried to make a recursive function but it also does not go inside the "then" block of the function call.

Only this method works but its not running through the correct order.

```
function uploadImages(sku) {
    var promises = [];

    for(var x=0; x<10; x++) {
      promises.push(uploadImage(sku,(x+1)+".jpg")));
    }

    return Q.all(promises).then(function (res) {
      return sku;
    });
}
```

My recursive solution looks like this:

```
function uploadImages(sku,current,max) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    if(current<=max) {
      uploadImage(sku,current+'.jpg').then(function (res) {
        if(res) {
          uploadImages(sku,current+1,max);
        }
      }, function (err) {
        deferred.reject();
      });
    } else {
      deferred.resolve(sku);
    }

    return deferred.promise;
 }
```

What I'm looking for is something like this (but thats not the way to  implement):

```
 return uploadImage(sku,"1.jpg").then(function(res) {
      return uploadImage(sku,"2.jpg").then(function(res) {
        return uploadImage(sku,"3.jpg").then(function(res) {
          return uploadImage(sku,"4.jpg").then(function(res) {
            return uploadImage(sku,"5.jpg").then(function(res) {
              return uploadImage(sku,"6.jpg").then(function(res) {
                return uploadImage(sku,"7.jpg").then(function(res) {
                  return uploadImage(sku,"8.jpg").then(function(res) {
                    return uploadImage(sku,"9.jpg").then(function(res) {
                      return uploadImage(sku,"10.jpg").then(function(res) {
                        return sku;
                      });
                    });
                  });
                });
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

So what is the best practice for my purpose?

Comment: What do you mean "in correct order"?

Comment: For example after image1 is uploaded correctly it should start uploading image2

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100245/how-can-i-execute-array-of-promises-in-sequential-order and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586110/resolve-promises-one-after-another-i-e-in-sequence

Comment: Please show us your recursive attempt, it should work.

Comment: @Bergi I've edited my posting please take a look at it.

Comment: @Kingalione: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572), and `return` the promise from the recursive call from the `then` callback, and it will work.

Comment: I didn't really understand how to solve the antipattern. Can you show it to me with this code please?

Comment: @Kingalione please see my updated answer.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks, now I understand what @Bergi meant. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept of "correct order" for async calls because they are just that -- asynchronous and they can end at any point.

In your the callback in `Q.all(promises).then(...)` you should have the responses in the order that you made them, but the order of your console logs *may not* be in the same order due their asynchronous nature.

---

In your case, you can probably do it recursively:

```
function uploadFiles(sku, current, max) {
     return uploadImage(sku, current + '.jpg').then(function (sku) {
          if (current > max) { return sku; }

          return uploadFiles(sku, current + 1, max);
     });
}

// use it
uploadFiles('SOME_SKU', 1, 10).then(function (sku) {
    // ALL DONE!
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to catch exceptions from the promise.

```
return Q.all(promises).then(function (res) {
  return sku;
})
.catch(function (error) {
    // Handle any error from all above steps
});
```

Comment: I am not sure how this answers the question.

Comment: Catching the error should give you/us more information about the error and why the promise is never fulfilled.

Comment: @YordanIvanov: But there is no error in the OP's code? There are mistakes, sure, but nothing that throws an exception that would reject the promise.