# Sequential promises using async/await in vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to solve running an array of promises using async, in sequential order, but specifically how to pass the resolved value from one function to the next.

All the examples I have seen so far just show something like this:

```
const value = await foo();
const value2 = await bar(value);
```

I'd prefer to do run them all together sequentially from an array, but just not sure how to pass the returned values between them (since I'm trying to use vanilla js async here).

Comment: What do you mean “all together” and “sequentially”?

Comment: I mean that to get `value2`, I need to first get `value`. But I want to run them from an array of promise functions ie [foo, bar]. I currently have two, but I may want to run them through a sequence of 10 functions, each one transforming the input and passing the transformed data to the next one, until the data has run through all the functions in the array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I execute array of promises in sequential order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100245/how-can-i-execute-array-of-promises-in-sequential-order)

Comment: That does not use vanilla JS (as I understand it since it uses RSVP, Q, etc), also it just calls the functions, it does not seem to show the returned values in the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a pipeline like this:

```
let fnArray  = [foo,  bar, baz];
let lastResult;
for(let i = 0; i < fnArray.length; i++) {
     lastResult = await fnArray[i](lastResult);
}
```

Comment: That looks like a great solution, will give it a try, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap them in a `.then()`

```
foo()
    .then(valueFoo => bar(valueFoo))
    .then(valueBar => AnotherFunc(valueBar))
    .catch(e => { console.log(e)})
```

Comment: What you’ve suggested is what the OP is already doing, just without the use of await.

Comment: with `.then()` you "await" the result of the function called before hand ;)