# Calling $http.post in batches and chaining promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have a use case where I have to call `$http.post(request)` on batches of the input data.
For this, I created an array of requests. For each of them, I need to get the response of `$http.post()`, append it to an existing array and pass it to a rendering function. I have to make the next call only when the previous one completes and since `$http.post()` returns a promise ([according to this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns)), I am trying to do this using the `reduce` function.

```js
function callToHttpPost(request) {
    return $http.post('someurl', request);
}

function outerFunc($scope, someId) {
    let completeArray = [];
    let arrayOfRequests = getRequestInBatches();

    arrayOfRequests.reduce((promiseChain, currentRequest) => {
        console.log(promiseChain);
        return promiseChain.then((previousResponse) => {
            completeArray.push.apply(completeArray, previousResponse.data);
            render($scope, completeArray, someId);
            return callToHttpPost(currentRequest);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve()).catch(e => errorHandler($scope, e, someId));
}
```

(I have referred [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#running_promises_in_sequence) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100245/how-can-i-execute-array-of-promises-in-sequential-order))

But this gives me `TypeError: previousResponse is undefined`. The log statement shows the first promise as resolved (since it is the initial value passed to the `reduce` function), but the other promises show up as `rejected` due to this error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: It's not clear why you're returning `Promise.resolve()).catch(e => errorHandler($scope, e, someId)` as the accumulator. Shouldn't it just be an array of requests?

Comment: Promise.resolve() is the second argument to the `reduce` function. `arrayOfRequests.reduce(callbackFn, initialValue)` and the `.catch(e => errorHandler($scope, e, someId)` is for error handling. `Promise.resolve().then().then().then()....catch()` is what I am trying to achieve, but I encounter this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in passing the initial value. In the first iteration of the reduce function, `Promise.resolve()` returns `undefined`. This is what is passed as `previousResponse`. Passing `Promise.resolve({ data: [] })` as the `initialValue` to the reduce function solved the issue.

```js
arrayOfRequests.reduce((promiseChain, currentRequest) => {
    console.log(promiseChain);
    return promiseChain.then((previousResponse) => {
        completeArray.push.apply(completeArray, previousResponse.data);
        render($scope, completeArray, someId);
        return callToHttpPost(currentRequest);
    });
}, Promise.resolve({ data: [] }))
.then(response => {
    completeArray.push.apply(completeArray, previousResponse.data);
    render($scope, completeArray, someId);
    displaySuccessNotification();
})
.catch(e => errorHandler($scope, e, someId));
```

---

(edited to handle the final response)

Comment: This is still wrong, though: it ignores the result of the last `callToHttpPost`. Instead, the accumulator `promiseChain` should hold the `completeArray`

Answer (score 2):

##### Using vanilla Javascript

If the `outerFunc` function can be used in an `async` context (which it looks like it can, given that it returns nothing and the results are passed to the `render` function as they are built up), you could clean that right up, paring it down to:

```
async function outerFunc ($scope, someId) {
  const completeArray = []; 

  try {
    for (const request of getRequestInBatches()) {
      const { data } = await callToHttpPost(request);
      completeArray.push(...data);
      render($scope, completeArray, someId);
    }   
  } catch (e) {
    errorHandler($scope, e, someId);
  }
}
```

The sequential nature will be enforced by the [`async`/`await`](https://javascript.info/async-await) keywords.

##### Using RxJS

If you're able to add a dependency on [RxJS](https://rxjs.dev/), your can change the function to:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';

function outerFunc ($scope, someId) {
  from(getRequestInBatches()).pipe(
    concatMap(callToHttpPost),
    scan((completeArray, { data }) => completeArray.concat(...data), []) 
  ).subscribe(
    completeArray => render($scope, completeArray, someId),
    e => errorHandler($scope, e, someId)
  );  
}
```

which revolves around the use of [`Observable`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Observable) instead of `Promise`. In this version, the sequential nature is enforced by the [`concatMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/concatMap) operator, and the complete array of results is reduced and emitted while being built up by the [`scan`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/scan) operator.

Comment: Ah yes, `apply`. Thanks for the edit @Bergi