# Sequentially process promises in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new to NodeJS. I am facing an issue where I want to sequentially process the promises. At the moment the entire loop is processed without waiting the 1st promise to execute.

```
test.pages.forEach(page => {
  generate({      
    inline: false,
    base: './',
    src: url,
    dimensions: [
        {
          width: 576,
          height: 900
          
        }
    ],

    target: {
      css: page.fileName,
    },
    ignore: {
      atrule: ['@font-face'],      
    },
  });
  
});
```

I want to sequentially process one by one. If I add await keyword before generate thinking it would wait and then process the 2nd item but it throws error:

```
await generate({
  ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:119:18)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:468:14)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:68:21)

Node.js v18.17.1
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: _"process the promises"_... what promises?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I execute array of promises in sequential order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100245/how-can-i-execute-array-of-promises-in-sequential-order) Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43189700/283366)

Comment: Just replace `.forEach` with a proper `for (const page of test.pages) {...` loop and you can use await. As a bonus it also uses less RAM and CPU than the `.forEach()` method

Comment: @slebetman you are a hero my love. But could you please explain why the above is working or is it just a language implementation?

Comment: For loops have been designed to work with `await`. That's just how it is. It does not have to be `for..of` you can even do a regular `for (let x=0; x<y; x++)` loop. It's just `for..of` has the exact semantics of foreach only better because 1. it works with `await`, 2. it is faster and 3 it uses less memory (a function call allocates an entire stack frame whereas a for loop is just syntax)